# How many contract are currently deployed on the Ethereum blockchain?

Tags: blockchain, contract-deployment

I was recently asked what percentage of transactions represent smart contract deployments on Ethereum, and had no immediate answer.

It is probably easier to ask **how many contracts are currently deployed on Ethereum** - I had a look around at Etherscan but couldn't find any statistics of direct relevance. I am aware of [this answer](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/6672/how-to-list-all-the-contracts-currently-on-the-blockchain), but [ether.camp](https://live.ether.camp/transactions) appears to only show a real-time list of contract deployments and no summary stats.

Are there any estimates on the number of contracts deployed, and if so, what sources are available to monitor such developments?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From https://etherscan.io/accounts/c, currently there are 123,376 contracts deployed on the Ethereum blockchain holding 8,551,373.447 ethers.

Out of the 123,376 contracts, there are 545 verified contracts, where the source code is independently compiled and compared with the virtual machine code deployed to the blockchain - from https://etherscan.io/contractsVerified.

For comparison, there are 475,244 externally owned accounts (normal addresses) holding 75,384,547.973 ethers - from https://etherscan.io/accounts/a.

Comment: Update for October 2017: 2 million :)