# Is there a programmatic way of querying the blockchain for the list of deployed contracts?

Tags: contract-development, blockchain, contract-deployment, internal-transactions

Do you have any suggestions on how I could query the blockchain via web3 or something so that I can get a list of deployed contracts?

Comment: https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/q/8648/259

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How many contract are currently deployed on the Ethereum blockchain?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/8648/how-many-contract-are-currently-deployed-on-the-ethereum-blockchain)

Comment: not a duplicate, the older question just points to etherscan. it has no suggestions regarding a programmatic query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a list of **deployed** contracts, one way is to get all [transaction receipts](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JavaScript-API#web3ethgettransactionreceipt) and print the `contractAddress`.

---

For a list of all contracts, since contracts can create contracts, you would need to execute the EVM bytecode of every transaction to see what contracts are created by a transaction, similar to
[How to get contract internal transactions](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/3417/how-to-get-contract-internal-transactions).