# How many Smart Contracts are deployed on Ethereum at the moment?

Tags: statistics

I have seen the same question being asked before, but it was kind of out of date.

Etherscan.io only shows me the last 500 verified Smart Contracts on Ethereum, but not the total number.

Is there an easy way to find the current number?

Thank you

Comment: there is no simple way to get it, I think you should iterate through each transaction since day 0 and check if it create a contract. I assume millions XD

Comment: The same question from a few years ago https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/8648/how-many-contract-are-currently-deployed-on-the-ethereum-blockchain, the links point to some pages from Etherscan but they no longer provide information about smart contracts only accounts.

Comment: Related: https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/43181