# How to get Ethereum Metadata? admin_getContractInfo does not exist

Tags: go-ethereum, solidity, contract-development, contract-debugging

Is there a way to get the metadata(bytecode, ABI) of a deployed contract if you only know the address of the contract?

In geth there is a function in the admin interface called ***getContractinfo()***, but I get an error when I call it: ***The method admin_getContractInfo does not exist/is not available***

In the documentation(https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/wiki/Contracts-and-Transactions) I saw an example but I don't think it works:

```
// get the contract info for contract address to do manual verification
var info = admin.getContractInfo(address) // lookup, fetch, decode
var source = info.source;
var abiDef = info.abiDefinition
```

Comment: What version of Geth are you using? Are you calling it from an `attach`ed console? Do any of the other `admin` commands work?

Comment: Yes other admin commands work. I am using an attached console. I am using 1.4.3 version.

Answer (score 3):

For the bytecode, you can use `web3.eth.getCode(address)`.

For the ABI, you need to get it from whoever wrote the contract, or generate the ABI from the source code.  Generally, you can't figure out the function names from the bytecode, because the bytecode only has a hash of the names, more info:
[Do I need a compiled contract just to get the ABI definition?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/1437/do-i-need-a-compiled-contract-just-to-get-the-abi-definition)

---

`admin.getContractInfo` seems to have been [removed](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/commit/9eb50a962400bae76478aa7fdc07b66c8fc2d81a).  (Note that to use `getContractInfo`, the earlier steps https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/wiki/Contracts-and-Transactions#contract-info-metadata  including `saveInfo` were also needed.)

Comment: Why was getContractInfo removed? This seems like a necessary function. How will I listen to another contract's events? There is not a "loadABI" function to do it from a file, even if the contract owner gave me the source code

Answer (score 1):

Yes, but it's a bit of a hassle (you have to reverse engineer the code/be familiar with the EVM byte code).

There is an example [here](https://medium.com/@kpcb_edge/our-thoughts-on-ethereum-continued-3e7383c63779#.75v2bp6bb) with the deployed contract [here](https://etherchain.org/account/0x121d30ecf48b11edd651249a3a110f48d42ba710#code).