# How to decode input data from a contract transaction without ABI?

Tags: transactions, javascript

I've found some libraries which decode input from transaction,  but all of them require ABI of contract.

Can I decode input data if I know only txHash, contract address and input data?

How etherscan does it?

Here is an example: 
https://etherscan.io/tx/0x42afb58ccd19e5f30c4e41a352cdc99e6e3f5ba05191215123e935dc15f55c93

Input data is decoded, but there is no source code (ABI) for that contract.

P.S. I'm interested more in JS libraries, but programming language is not so important.

Comment: This is question is somehow related https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/7927/how-to-parse-abi-out-of-contract-code , there's a listing of know signatures at https://www.4byte.directory/ .

Comment: @Ismael Thank you! This site 4byte.directory is very useful and it finds signatures for many contacts. I'll try to decode with web3 library: web3.eth.abi.decodeParameters(typesArray, hexString);