# Why do Solidity examples use bytes32 type instead of string?

Tags: solidity, contract-design, contract-development, string, bytes32

In many Solidity examples I read that use strings for parameters or return values, I see they are typed as `bytes32` although there's a `string` type. What is the real reason for that?
Thanks.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

2 main reasons:

1. Contracts [currently cannot read a `string`](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/3788/42) that's returned by another contract.
2. The [EVM has a word-size of 32 bytes](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/q/2327/42), so it is "optimized" for dealing with data in chunks of 32 bytes.  (Compilers, such as Solidity, have to do more work and generate more bytecode when data isn't in chunks of 32 bytes, which effectively leads to higher gas cost.)

Comment: Would this mean that if using string instead of byte32 this would make the contract split the string in 32 bytes chunk and then have an unpredictable number of chunks and thus have an unpredictable gas usage on this part of the code?

Comment: Sounds correct to me, and the unpredictable gas usage is another good consideration.

Answer (score 9):

I have test in this site https://ethfiddle.com/zLxE5Y-8B4

```
contract TestGas {
    string constant statictext = "Hello World";
    bytes11 constant byteText11 = "Hello World";
    bytes32 constant byteText32 = "Hello World";

    function  getString() payable public  returns(string){
        return statictext;
    }

    function  getByte11() payable public returns(bytes11){
        return byteText11;
    }

    function  getByte32() payable public returns(bytes32){
        return byteText32;
    }
}
```

And function `getString` spent **21875** gas,

function `getByte11` spent **21509** gas,

function `getByte32` spent **21487** gas.

So if your string length is fixed, just use bytes32.

Comment: why does the `getByte11` cost more gas than `getByte32`?

Comment: @SaadMalik The EVM works with 32 bytes words. When your data is smaller than 32 bytes, every operation related to this data will downscale from 256 bits to 8 bits(32 bytes = 256 bits), so EVM need much more gas.