# Use string type or bytes32?

Tags: solidity, contract-development, contract-design, string, bytes32

What are the benefits to using `string` datatypes over `bytes32` to represent text data. It seems my contract runs into an out of gas exception when I switch the data structures from `bytes32` to `string`.

Answer (score 67, accepted):

### Why `string` instead of `bytes32`?

Use `string` for arbitrary-length string (UTF-8) data that's longer than 32 bytes.  Frontends can decode a long string easier using methods like [web3.toAscii](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JavaScript-API#web3toascii) or UTF-8 (when [issues](https://github.com/ethereum/web3.js/issues?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=is%3Aissue%20utf8) are fixed), instead of implementing the logic of UTF-8 decoding a series of `bytes32`.

From [Solidity docs:](http://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/develop/types.html#dynamically-sized-byte-array)

> As a rule of thumb, use `bytes` for arbitrary-length raw byte data and
>   `string` for arbitrary-length string (UTF-8) data. If you can limit the
>   length to a certain number of bytes, always use one of `bytes1` to
>   `bytes32` because they are much cheaper.

[String literals](http://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/develop/types.html#string-literals) may also be helpful or convenient:

> String literals are written with either double or single-quotes ("foo"
>   or 'bar')...
>
> String literals support escape characters, such as \n, \xNN and
>   \uNNNN. \xNN takes a hex value and inserts the appropriate byte, while
>   \uNNNN takes a Unicode codepoint and inserts an UTF-8 sequence.

---

### Why `bytes32` instead of `string`?

Answered in [Why do Solidity examples use bytes32 type instead of string?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/3795/why-solidity-uses-bytes32-type-instead-of-string)

`bytes32` uses less gas because it fits in a single word of the EVM, and `string` is a dynamically sized-type which has current limitations in Solidity (such as can't be returned from a function to a contract).

Comment: I am not sure if I understood the last sentence - string return types work in current Solidity compiler.

Comment: @MikkoOhtamaa Emphasis is *to a contract*: I don't think http://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/3788/42 is supported yet.

Comment: Ok so if you have a controlling contract and it's accessing data from another contract which is returning text that is longer than 32 bytes, you would need to return it in a bytes32 array?

Comment: @ethereal Sounds right, give a size to the array like bytes32[3].  There may be assembly ways to get the size of the data being returned and avoiding a hardcoded size, for example the contracts in https://github.com/ownage-ltd/ether-router

Comment: If a contract cannot access another contract's string variables, then what can? Can web3? What if I want to store a list or array of 60-character strings, but I will need to access them from another contract or program, how do I do it?

Comment: If I know that is have say a 50 long string to save, is it cheaper to use two bytes32 and to split it or to use bytes/string ?

Comment: @ClementWalter Yes, I think two bytes32 cheaper. Your frontend/UI should do the split/concat. You probably want to test both to see which you prefer overall.

Answer (score 26):

Like the other post said, you only want to use strings for dynamically allocated data, otherwise Byte32 is going to perform better. Bytes32 is also  going to be better in gas. If you want to play around with it, I built a little fiddle of it https://ethfiddle.com/70ipaEIFdk

Byte used 21465 gas

String used 21897 gas

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.18;

contract SampleOverflow {
  string constant statictext = "HelloStackOverFlow";
  bytes32 constant byteText = "HelloStackOverFlow";
  function  getString() payable public  returns(string){
    return statictext;
  }

  function  getByte() payable public returns(bytes32){
    return byteText;
  }
}
```

Get Byte
[image]

Get String
[image]
https://ethfiddle.com/70ipaEIFdk

Comment: that fiddle doesn't work. I think it's to do with the escaped double quotes. I tried removing escape caharacters but eth fiddle didnt liek that either.. Here's your example working https://ethfiddle.com/SeXTGt-AWi

Answer (score 2):

bytes32 means string with max length 32, It takes less memory than string for the same length of the string.

So, when your data is not more than 32 bytes (32 words), use bytes32.

If the length of the string is not defined, use just `bytes`.

also, byte8,byte16,byte32 are all available. You can use any as per conditions.

Comment: Thanks for the simple answer, just want you to clarify the third statement "If the length of the string is not defined, use string." is that case we can use bytes instead of string or bytes32, right?

Comment: bytes32 can store up to 32 letters (ASCII), if you require more length, use String.

Comment: yah i get you but we can use *bytes* not *byte32* to store more length instead of String?

Comment: o ya, you are right, sorry, i am updating answer.

Comment: if just leaving at 'bytes', is it set to a certain default #? if so, what is that, is it 'bytes32'?

Answer (score 0):

Your system architecture understands that Bytes32 has a maximum of 32 bytes of memory allocation. 1 byte = 1 ASCII character.
However, the memory allocation of String data type is not fixed. Hence dynamic.

The design approach will be:

1. If your intention is to save gas, limit your character range to, 0 to 32 (i.e 32 characters= 32 bytes). Bytes32 is most suitable.
2. If you are not concerned about gas expense, not sure of the number of characters you are expecting, *maybe in your contract function* (i.e maybe you are expecting a text as much as Harry Potter novel (*lol*). String data type is most suitable