# Hit a require or revert statement somewhere in its constructor?

Tags: solidity, truffle, ganache

I'm trying to fork a [token contract](https://bscscan.com/address/0x5e90253fbae4dab78aa351f4e6fed08a64ab5590#code) and deploy it locally using ganache but I keep running into the following error:

[image: error]

I have tried to debug the error using `truffle debug 'transaction'` and find the following:

[image: debug]

Now since there's no assert(), revert(), or require() statement I believe it's an out-of-gas exception error. However, one odd thing I've noticed is that after commenting out those two lines and trying to compile it still throws an error on those lines:

[image: debug2]

According to [this](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/28813/how-to-write-an-optimized-gas-cost-smart-contract) post, comments do not affect the gas cost and I don't see how commented out code could be throwing one of the other errors.

Does anyone know what's going on here?

Comment: You should provide your Solidity code in question to we can understand the problem.

Comment: @Kiasha Hi, the code in question is linked at the very start of the post. I've simply copy pasted that code and then imported its artifact into 1_initial_migration.js and and then attempted to deploy it.

Comment: what means `address(0)` in constructor?

Comment: @Kiasha 0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000

Comment: Why are you using a function in constructor that never implemented beforehand. I mean `.factory()` in: `uniswapV2Pair =` `IUniswapV2Factory(_uniswapV2Router.factory())`
           `.createPair(address(this), _uniswapV2Router.WETH()); `

Comment: @Kiasha I'm not entirely sure. I thought maybe it's implemented here https://bscscan.com/address/0x05ff2b0db69458a0750badebc4f9e13add608c7f#code but it's not. Areas of interest around lines 51 and 362. Still not seeing where factory() is implemented.

Comment: Please how did you deploy this on ganache? I am assuming this is where the bug is? IUniswapV2Router02 _uniswapV2Router = IUniswapV2Router02(0x05fF2B0DB69458A0750badebc4f9e13aDd608C7F); // Create a uniswap pair for this new token uniswapV2Pair = IUniswapV2Factory(_uniswapV2Router.factory()) .createPair(address(this), _uniswapV2Router.WETH());

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just before those lines I see Bonfire creating a pair on Uniswap. Did you deployed that contract as well on Ganache? is Ganache forking mainnet?

```
IUniswapV2Router02 _uniswapV2Router = IUniswapV2Router02(0x05fF2B0DB69458A0750badebc4f9e13aDd608C7F);

// Create a uniswap pair for this new token
uniswapV2Pair = IUniswapV2Factory(_uniswapV2Router.factory())
            .createPair(address(this), _uniswapV2Router.WETH());
```

Comment: I haven't deployed that contract on Ganache or forked the mainnet. I suppose that is likely the error then?

Comment: Probably and this could explain the out-of-gas error.