# (Solidity) Is using 'string' safe?

Tags: solidity, remix, string

Maybe stupid question, but just want to be sure before deploying contract on main net. In my contract user can change his name(:string) to whatever he likes. 
Is it totally safe? I mean, is here some chance of 'overflow' string, change any other variables through that or something similar as SQL Injection?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know you can't really 'overflow' it or anything similar. You can find a lot more information here: [Use string type or bytes32?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/11556/use-string-type-or-bytes32)

What your users *can* do is assign a very long string and if your contract uses the string for something it will cost a lot of gas to process. So consider limiting the length (by using `bytes`).