# How to pass arguments correctly?

Tags: solidity, remix

[image]
So, I can't understand how to input correctly args

Comment: just define it as array of bytes. eg. ["0x123", "0x456"]

Answer (score 1):

As @mirg stated in his comment
in Remix input you can provide an array such `["alfa", "beta","0x12"]` of random size as you have an dynamic array.

check here why bytes32
[Use string type or bytes32?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/11556/use-string-type-or-bytes32)