# Declare string inside function

Tags: solidity, string

I tried to declare string inside my function but it doesn't work.

How to declare string inside function?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect it has to do with some already answered question like
[Why do Solidity examples use bytes32 type instead of string?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/3795/why-do-solidity-examples-use-bytes32-type-instead-of-string)

However, a code like the one below seems to work around without declaring a string.

```
contract A{
        function f() constant returns(string){
            var s="hello";
            return s;
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

looms like compiler is not getting the righ context for the string declaration.

As such below default rules applies to decide on the storage option based on context:
- default storage for member variable is 'storage'
- default for function parameters and return types is 'memory'

In EVM context, string is an array which has an extra annotation -'data location'. Thsi could be either 'memory' or 'storage'.

Seems in the below programm, it exolicitly looking to define the storage option.

As you can see below, I specified the stogare option as 'memory' and its compiling fine.

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.4;

contract Test {

    function print() constant returns(string){
        string memory x = "ddd";
        return x;
    } 
}
```