# Deploying custom code to private network results in "instrinsic gas too low" or "check your gas" errors

Tags: private-blockchain, testnets, testing, documentation

TL:DR My first contract fails to deploy reporting variously:

- `Error: intrinsic gas too low undefined`
- `Error: The contract code couldn't be stored, please check your gas amount. undefined`

Having just investigated Hyperledger Fabric, I thought I'd try my hand at converting it's [fabcar](https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/write_first_app.html) example to Ethereum.

I'm running an Ethereum private network with:

`geth --dev --ipcpath ${HOME}/Library/Ethereum/geth.ipc`

and then attaching to this with:

`geth attach ipc://${HOME}/Library/Ethereum/geth.ipc`

I wrote `fabcarSource.sol` using an example ([link](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/12947)) and taking some feedback from `solc`. The original uses an associative array (JavaScript object here) but the sample I followed uses a regular array and so I am here at least to get this deployed. [Feedback welcome.]

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.9;

contract Fabcar {

    struct Car {
        string colour;
        string make;
        string model;
        string owner;
    }

    Car[] cars;

    function changeCarOwner (uint k, string newOwner)
        public
    {
        if (k<cars.length) {
            cars[k].owner = newOwner;
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
    function createCar(string colour, string make, string model, string owner)
        public
        returns (uint)
    {
        return cars.push(Car(colour,make,model,owner));
    }
    function initLedger() {
        cars.push(Car("Dark Gray","Ford","Escape","Daz"));
        cars.push(Car("Blue","Audi","A5","Karo"));
    }
    function queryCar(uint k)
        public
        view
        returns (Car)
    {
        if (k<cars.length) {
            return cars[k];
        }
    }
    function queryAllCars()
        public
        view
        returns (Car[])
    {
        return cars;
    }


}
```

Per my guide ([link](http://blog.csdn.net/weixin_40401264/article/details/78136346)):

```
echo var fabcarSource = > fabcarSource.js && \
solc --combined-json abi,bin,interface fabcarSource.sol >> fabcarSource.js
```

and then:

```
personal.unlockAccount(eth.accounts[0]);
loadScript("fabcarSource.js");
var fabcarContract = web3.eth.contract(
  JSON.parse(fabcarSource.contracts["fabcarSource.sol:Fabcar"].abi));
var gasValue = eth.estimateGas({
  date:"0x"+fabcarSource.contracts["fabcarSource.sol:Fabcar"].bin
});
```

and a check:

```
> gasValue
53000
```

and, after more Googling:

```
> eth.getBlock("latest").gasLimit
4712388
> eth.getBalance(eth.coinbase)
4.875e+21
```

BUT:

```
var fabcar=fabcarContract.new(
  {
    from:eth.accounts[0],
    data:"0x"+fabcarSource.contracts["fabcarSource.sol:Fabcar"].bin,
    gas:400000
  },
  function(e,contract){
    console.log(e,contract);
    if (typeof contract.address !== "undefined") {
      console.log(
        "Contract mined! Address: " + contract.address + 
        " transactionHash: " + contract.transactionHash
      );
    }
  }
);
```

and using `gasValue`, `gasValue+50000`, `300000` ([tutorial](https://ethereum.org/greeter)), `500000` results in the errors up-top.

Any help would be much appreciated!

As others have pointed out, the getting started instructions are frustratingly out-of-date and increase abandonment. Please fix!

https://ethereum.org/greeter

I found several **very** helpful links: one on StackExchange for using a private network ([link](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/2571)) and another that got me a sample deployed ([link](http://blog.csdn.net/weixin_40401264/article/details/78136346)) and I was able to get greeter deployed thanks to them. But this took time and I remain close to giving up.

Comment: Aha! Perhaps partly a consequence of (a) indeterminate string sizes with the Car struct (and functions)? I found this question regarding Solidity examples using bytes32 instead of string; (b) missing 'payable' for mutators. I will see whether these make a difference to the Deployment. (https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/3795/why-do-solidity-examples-use-bytes32-type-instead-of-string)

Comment: These did not make a difference :-(

Comment: I was able to use https://ethereum.github.io/browser-solidity to create a web3deploy that I was (!) able to deploy. It has `gas: '4700000'` (string) but... I then encounter problems with an inability to return Structs from functions etc.

Comment: I am able to deploy using my example above by setting gas to 4.7m as with the web3deploy but as an int value not a string. So, that's one problem solved.

Answer (score 0):

I believe my deployment errors were solely related to an incorrect gas value.

It remains unclear to me how to determine the `gas` value for deployments when eth.estimateGas was so far from the value I needed.

Setting the gas value to 4.7m (in this case) works, reliably.

The value is approximately `eth.getBlock("latest").gasLimit` (4,712,388) and I assume that's relevant.