# Does RLP specify integer encoding?

Tags: protocol, rlp

The RLP specification says the following about integers:

> The only purpose of RLP is to encode structure; encoding specific atomic data types (eg. strings, ints, floats) is left up to higher-order protocols; in Ethereum integers must be represented in big endian binary form with no leading zeroes (thus making the integer value zero be equivalent to the empty byte array).

When it says "in Ethereum" does this actually mean in the ETH subprotocol alone, or does this mean in the body of work 'Ethereum' and specifically the RLP protocol? If the latter, this paragraph seems to contradict itself. On the one hand, it is saying that RLP leaves the encoding to higher protocols, but on the other says that RLP demands big endian integers with all leading zeroes skipped.

Where should this encoding be implemented then? In the RLP protocol, or should there be a specific type 'EthereumInteger' distinct from 'integer'?

Perhaps a better question might be, to whom should this sort of question best be addressed and where?

Comment: The answer below is correct if it includes all the comments.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[RLP](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/RLP) deals only in structures made up of bytes (binary data). It doesn't care whether those bytes represent strings, integers, big integers, floating point numbers or whatever. This is in the sentence prior to the one you quoted,

> The purpose of RLP (Recursive Length Prefix) is to encode arbitrarily nested arrays of *binary data*...

On your question:

> ...but on the other says that RLP demands big endian integers with all leading zeroes skipped.

No, it doesn't say that. It says that in *Ethereum* integers are represented as big endian with no leading zero bytes.

RLP is not specific to Ethereum (although it was developed for Ethereum AFAIK). The point is that Ethereum is one of the "higher-order protocols" mentioned in this sentence. So it all makes sense:

- RLP encodes arbitrary binary data and doesn't care what it represents in any higher-level protocol;
- [implied "As an example of such a higher order protocol..."] Ethereum integers must be represented in big endian binary form with no leading zeroes.

Admittedly the Ethereum part could be omitted and things might be clearer. I think the author just wanted to give an example of such a higher-order protocol for concreteness.

Comment: Thanks for that but I do not yet know if that is accurate. For example Ethereum integers in method calls are not encoded in this way. This looks more like it is trying to say that the ethereum specific implementation of RLP must encode like this, not the whole body of work Ethereum. And when you say other protocols, do you mean just ETH, or devp2p or shh etc?

Comment: "For example Ethereum integers in method calls are not encoded in this way." - these are not integers, they are ABI byte strings.  A smart contract may choose to interpret them as integers, or as something else. This is not RLP-related.  RLP is RLP totally independently of Etherem. Look at its sample code in the article; there's nothing Ethereum-specific in it.

Comment: OK thanks for that. I am just trying to learn. Can you point to where it is specified that Ethereum integers are represented as big-endian no-leading-zero bytes? Also in the RLP protocol specification the " length of the string in binary form" is what data type, if not big endian non-leading-zero integer? Eg: this phrase in the RLP spec :"followed by the length of the payload".

Comment: Learning is good  :-)  The Ethereum [Yellow Paper](https://yellowpaper.io) is the canonical reference. For the specific Ethereum implementation of RLP, see Appendix B. At the end of that appendix you can see a statement that (in Ethereum clients) "if an expected fragment is decoded as a scalar and leading zeroes are found in the byte
sequence" it is to be considered invalid. For big-endian, see the first sentence of Appendix H. It's only in the RLP encoding of integers in Ethereum that leading zero bytes *must* be dropped. It's not a general feature of Ethereum per se.

Comment: Thank you again. The issue I am having is whether to implement a type "Ethereum Integer" that maintains its own byte representation, or to implement those details in an Ethereum specific version of RLP. (I am developing a light client) Though I have not yet looked at those Yellow Paper appendices, I see nothing yet that suggests that anything other than Ethereum RLP requires this. Also the Wiki documentation for RLP seems to contradict your quote from the Appendix B. Note that the encoding for the length of the length of the string is an integer, and is specific to RLP.

Comment: I see it now....the wiki doc says this "plus the length in bytes of the length of the string in binary form" but the Yellow Paper says this: "prefixed by the minimal-length byte-array which when interpreted
as a big-endian integer is equal to the length of the input byte array"

Comment: If you conform the the spec in Appendix B then you will be fine for an Ethereum client. RLP is more general, but Ethereum adds this constraint about leading zeroes on integer quantities, which I suppose requires an Ethereum-specific implementation (not in RLP itself - RLP knows nothing except bytes and lengths/structure - but in the processing of input to and output from RLP). The YP is canonical for Ethereum clients.

Comment: OK I have it now. Indeed, if the Appendix B in the Yellow Paper is *the* RLP spec, then according to that then the other protocols in  Ethereum do not say anything about minimal-length integer representation. It is only RLP, and it is part of the RLP spec. Thanks for helping me find the answer!

Comment: I think we have converged: Appendix B is the *Ethereum* RLP spec, and I agree with your other statements. Anyway, it's been interesting to revisit this. Best of luck with the light client!

Comment: Thank you. I am sure we will cross paths again. The future is blockchain.