# How to pass arbitrary bytes to a function (2016)

Tags: solidity, truffle, bytes

I'm trying to implement a contract which will store bytes blob, a dynamic bytes array.

For example I have following struct:

```
Sign {
    address signer;
    bytes16 signType;
    bytes   sign;
}
```

plus an event:

```
event Signed(
    bytes16 signType,
    bytes sign
);
```

and trying to set it:

```
function addSignature(byte16 signType, bytes sign) {
    // ... store data
    ... = Sign(msg.sender, signType, sign) 
    // raise event
    Sign(signType, sign);
}
```

The problem that I can't find a way to pass `bytes` to the function from Javascript.

I'm using Truffle, and tried following Javascript code:

```
var type = web3.fromAscii('test', 16);
var sign = [0x12, 0x34]; //also tried web3.toBigNumber('0x1234');
contract.addSignature(type, sign, {from: myAccount, gas: 2000000});
```

it makes a transaction, but I don't see correct value stored into my contact. For example by listening to `Signed` event I see that there're an empty array. If I try to read data, I got zeros (actually it's more weird, I get `signType` padded with long array of zeroes).

What is a proper way to use arbitrary bytes array? hot to send to contract, how to read?

PS I'm using Truffle with TestRPC.

Comment: Did you try simply `var sign = '0x1234';` ?  IIRC it worked for me, but I didn't use Truffle or TestRPC.

Comment: Also I don't know why signType is `byte16` but to isolate your issues, try with say a `uint` signType first: it's getting padded with zeros since `test` is only 4 bytes, and you're using `byte16`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

EDIT: See
[How to pass arbitrary bytes to a function in Remix](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/13483/how-to-pass-arbitrary-bytes-to-a-function-again)

The behavior in Remix was changed so see above; the following was for an older version of Remix / browser-solidity.

<s>To pass `bytes` to a function, pass the bytes as a hex string.</s>

Example in [Solidity Browser](https://chriseth.github.io/browser-solidity):

```
contract SimpleStorage {
    bytes storedData;
    function set(bytes x) {
        storedData = x;
    }
    function get() constant returns (bytes retVal) {
        return storedData;
    }
}
```

Click "Create", then in "Set" enter "0x1234" or any arbitrary hex string.

Click "Set", then "Get" and you will see your data, encoded according to the [ABI](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/q/234/42).

Comment: This answer is no longer correct, see http://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/13483/how-to-pass-arbitrary-bytes-to-a-function-again

Comment: Indeed, I updated question title and answer.  Not sure about precedence or need of now marking this as a duplicate.