# Accessing the last function parameter from msg.data

Tags: solidity, abi, fallback-function, calldata

I have a fallback (unnamed) function in my contract and I know that the last parameter (or first, does not matter) passed is always an uint. Is it possible to somehow access it though the msg.data?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, all parameters can be accessed from `msg.data` (EVM term is calldata).

The calldata is ABI encoded: [What is an ABI and why is it needed to interact with contracts?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/q/234/42)

Extracting the first parameter is simpler than others.  For the first parameter, skip the first 4 bytes (Method ID), and the next 32 bytes is the uint (left-padded) you are looking for.

If the parameter was the last, extracting it would be more involved especially if some of the parameters are [arrays, `strings`, or `bytes`](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/Ethereum-Contract-ABI#use-of-dynamic-types).

---

Note: There's [a case where the fallback function gets a very limited amount of gas](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/5992/how-much-computation-can-be-done-in-a-fallback-function), and in that case you might not be able to do what you'd like with the uint (like storing it).

Comment: In case of fallback function there might be no these 4 bytes of a method id.