# How do you get a string value from msg.data in the fallback function?

Tags: solidity, string, fallback-function, bytes, calldata

Im trying to do what The DAO did and do something when a sender sent money to my contract address. But im not sure how to.
The something I want to do is to just create a new user in a mapping with the string sent in the msg.data object.

I have heard about the fallback function, and thought I could extract the msg.data. But that seems to be bytes. Do I have to convert it? If so how do you do that?

Here is my code:

Premium.sol

```
struct User {
    address user;
    bool paid;
}

mapping(string => User) PremiumUsers;
address owner;


function Premium() {
    owner = msg.sender;
}

function () {
  var mail = byteconverterToString(msg.data);
  var newUser = PremiumUsers[mail];
  newUser.user = msg.sender;
  newUser.paid = true;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

[IF the fallback function only gets 2300 gas](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/5992/how-much-computation-can-be-done-in-a-fallback-function), it can't write to contract storage and here are 2 ideas.

### Option 1

You could add an explicit function like `receiveEther(string senderName`) in the contract.  web3.js can be used like `contractInstance.receiveEther("name of the sender", {value: web3.toWei(1, "ether"), ...})` and the contract could access the sender name and `msg.value` easily without [parsing](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/q/5684/42) the [ABI](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/234/what-is-an-abi-and-why-is-it-needed-to-interact-with-contracts).

### Option 2

If you want to avoid having a function the user has to call, then in your contract fallback function you emit an event with `msg.data`. The app listens for the event and can then parse and store the event data in a database, or if you want to store the data in the contract, the app makes a transaction to the contract to store the data.

A difference with option1 is that storing the data in the contract is a second transaction.  It is easier for the user that they don't need to call a function, but the app needs to be built robustly so that the data gets stored (whatever is listening for the event might go down).

Comment: Ok, il try, but I managed to change a string with the fallback function. Had a string saying no. And changing it in the fallbackfunction, to yes. But is that not writing to the contract storage?

Comment: So do you mean to have a filter inside the fallback function, then to have a app listening for that filter and running that function you mention here? I'm trying to avoid having a function the user has to call. I have used a function that uses a modifier which sets a price on the function. But then the user have to get the contract and call the function and everything. I would love to be able for people to just send money and instantly becomming a premium user with the given mailaddress.

Comment: Yes, your idea is good for "to avoid having a function the user has to call".  I added an option2 to the answer.  For your first comment, I added missing details to http://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/5992/how-much-computation-can-be-done-in-a-fallback-function.

Comment: Thanks I will se what I have time for, holding workshop tomorrow! I will grant it as a final answere when I get it to work!

Comment: @vonGohren No problem, good luck with the workshop!