# Have the curators emptied the whitelist of all splits after the 17 June attack?

Tags: security, the-dao

Would like to understand if an imitator attack is possible in the next days?
Explain if the split list of MEW https://www.myetherwallet.com/#dao-proposals reflects the whitelisting. 
Explain if splits are in the whitelist at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The split proposals do not need to be whitelisted so everyone with DAO tokens can attack the DAO to same way the first attack was performed.