# What does `call.value` mean and how did it allow the attack to The DAO?

Tags: security, contract-invocation, the-dao, fallback-function, reentrant-attacks

I'm trying to get some sense from the hysteria around the attack performed to The DAO smart contract.

I understand the high level explanations, but I'd like to grasp **how** this attack was performed.

I've read somewhere that this is related to the `call.value()` statement, but I don't understand why this is any different from regular `CALL`s.

Answer (score 5):

EDIT Dec 2019: `call.value()()` should now be used for transferring ether.

See:
[Is transfer() still safe after the Istanbul update (2300 gas limitation)?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/78124/is-transfer-still-safe-after-the-istanbul-update-2300-gas-limitation)

---

The following is the original answer.

`contract.call.gas(...).value(...)(...)` is a [way to add Ether and limit gas](http://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/latest/frequently-asked-questions.html#what-does-p-recipient-call-value-p-amount-p-data-do) when invoking a contract.  Basically, TheDAO used `call.value` to move Ether around in a generic way.

`contract.call.value(...)()` will [invoke](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/1585/why-does-an-empty-message-still-invoke-the-code-of-the-contrac) the [fallback function](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/5992/how-much-computation-can-be-done-in-a-fallback-function) at `contract` with almost all the gas that the caller has.  In a normal call like `contract.foo`, if `contract` is untrusted, it is much clearer that untrusted code (`foo`) is explicitly being invoked.

Another important difference is that any exceptions in `contract.foo` will bubble up: if `foo` runs Out of Gas, that exception immediately halts the transaction and reverts all state changes.  With `contract.call.value(...)()`, only a true or false is returned (the exception does not bubble up) and so you generally see code like `if (!contract.call.value(...)()) throw;`

Here's a glimpse into how the [reentrant attack](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/6344/42) was performed:
[How was the recursion created that lead to theDAO hack?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/6210/how-was-the-recursion-created-that-lead-to-thedao-hack).

Comment: "Almost"? Why not entirely all of his gas?

Comment: @JossieCalderon "Almost" is explained in the [footnote](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/5993/42) 'You cannot just say "send all my gas along with the call", you always have to give an explicit number.'