# How do I "Add Data" to a send transaction in Solidity

Tags: solidity, contract-invocation, security, calldata

In myetherwallet, there is an +Advanced: Add Data Section where I can add data to the transaction.

How can I add this same data in a transaction I make in Solidity?

[image]

Answer (score 3):

you need first to convert your string to the hexadecimal form using an online converter like http://string-functions.com/string-hex.aspx.

then put it in the data field (with 0x in the begining)

for example i've converted StackExchange into **0x**537461636b45786368616e6765

[image]

put it in the data field and then i've send successfully my transaction. you could check the transaction [here](https://ropsten.etherscan.io/tx/0x11a6727768cd81911c508ca914e1ab5263b01b17a6fae1ae10da7ed01b7a27fc).

[image]

you could press the convert to asci button in the bottom to get back the encoded sent string.

Comment: This answer does not show how it is done in Solidity. Downvote.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Solidity's low-level `call`, but be careful of [What does `call.value` mean and how did it allow the attack to The DAO?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/6391/what-does-call-value-mean-and-how-did-it-allow-the-attack-to-the-dao)

Example:

```
bytes calldata = 0xabcdef;
address to = 0x...
if (to.call(calldata)) {  // checks the return value
    ....
} else {
    ....
}
```

If you wanted to send along 2 ETH, the syntax would be:

```
to.call.value(2 * 10**18)(calldata);  // should check the return value
```

Some information in the Solidity [docs](http://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/develop/frequently-asked-questions.html#what-does-p-recipient-call-value-p-amount-p-data-do) and [FAQ](http://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/develop/frequently-asked-questions.html#why-is-the-low-level-function-call-less-favorable-than-instantiating-a-contract-with-a-variable-contractb-b-and-executing-its-functions-b-dosomething).

Whenever you use `call`, code in the `to` contract can be executed and since it can call you back in ways that you might not expect (like the [TheDAO](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/6391/what-does-call-value-mean-and-how-did-it-allow-the-attack-to-the-dao)), one should follow [guidelines](http://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/develop/security-considerations.html#use-the-checks-effects-interactions-pattern) such as updating state variables first and making `call` the very last step (an [example](http://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/develop/security-considerations.html#re-entrancy) that shows a state variable being set to zero first, and then a making a call to msg.sender).

Comment: why not to use send instead call?

Comment: @SigTouri Yes `send` or `transfer` is better if that's all that's needed.  The question was asking about adding data.

Comment: @eth How does one do this with token contract?  value() seems to expect ether.

Comment: @nueverest Tokens work quite different: you invoke a transfer function on a token contract and specify recipient and amount of tokens.  You're correct that value() should not be used.  Be careful and test first.