# What causes re-entrancy attacks?

Tags: ether, flash-loans

I’ve seen a lot of projects be hit with re-entrancy attacks caused by flash loans, what is the main process behind these attacks?

Comment: Reentrancy attacks are different from flash loan attacks. Reentrancy attacks don't need flash loans. However it looks like this might be answered here: https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/25947/how-can-defence-reentrancy-attack