# Is the DAO Hack attacker still full of ether?

Tags: ethereum-classic, dao

I'm actually studying what is happened in the DAO Hack for a research and I'm full of curiosity.

I read a lot of articles on Internet about this but I didn't found enought informations about what happened to the attacker after the fork. If he lost everything on ETH because of the fork itself, what about ETC? Anyone knows something about him and about that situation?

I appreciate a lot!

Comment: Hi Zerodrome! Welcome to Ethereum Stackexchange! Does this answer your question https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/6202/in-simple-terms-how-did-the-dao-get-hacked-and-funds-removed-from-it ?

Answer (score 0):

- The Remedy Fork was an "irregular state change ([proposed as EIP-779](https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-779)), transfering back the stolen fund to a safe contract (see this for more details and code : https://phyro.github.io/etc-history/chapters/struggle.html)
- Here is a summary of addresses : https://medium.com/@oaeee/the-rise-of-the-dark-dao-72b21a2212e3 (most of them are tagged on etherscan).
- The attacker(s) indeed kept things "are they were" on ETC (and have been, apparently, moving funds after - https://www.reddit.com/r/ethereum/comments/7iemi5/strange_activity_involved_with_the_address_the/)