# geth only syncing s few blocks at a time

Tags: go-ethereum, blockchain, synchronization

I am running geth with syncmode = full (because I need the full state tree of old blocks) and even though it was syncing over 200-300 blocks at a time a while ago, it is now only syncing a few blocks. Any idea why?
thanks

```
INFO [02-17|14:25:45] Imported new chain segment               blocks=3  txs=50 mgas=3.975 elapsed=9.658s  mgasps=0.412 number=2683028 hash=7723ea…f2eb9c
INFO [02-17|14:25:59] Imported new chain segment               blocks=7  txs=20 mgas=5.019 elapsed=14.057s mgasps=0.357 number=2683035 hash=d77b20…3d24aa
INFO [02-17|14:26:09] Imported new chain segment               blocks=3  txs=29 mgas=3.688 elapsed=9.971s  mgasps=0.370 number=2683038 hash=e6222f…28998e
INFO [02-17|14:26:24] Imported new chain segment               blocks=12 txs=64 mgas=5.841 elapsed=14.272s mgasps=0.409 number=2683050 hash=e6dbb5…036062
INFO [02-17|14:26:36] Imported new chain segment               blocks=6  txs=65 mgas=5.181 elapsed=12.149s mgasps=0.426 number=2683056 hash=edcf5a…2636b3
INFO [02-17|14:26:46] Imported new chain segment               blocks=4  txs=23 mgas=3.763 elapsed=10.503s mgasps=0.358 number=2683060 hash=4b806b…d392d4
INFO [02-17|14:26:55] Imported new chain segment               blocks=1  txs=18 mgas=2.617 elapsed=8.350s  mgasps=0.313 number=2683061 hash=895953…1a9caf
```

Comment: I believe you are experiencing the after-effects of the state-bloat attack: https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/33502/what-attacks-have-been-performed-against-the-ethereum-network-and-contracts

Comment: weird, that was on Q3 2016, Im already at block 2692478 which is from Nov 2016, should it take that long? And do u know when it is supposed to go back to normal? Thanks for your help.

Comment: I think the poking was still going on in January of 2017.