# Can I send ethereum to a contract outside of its constructor?

Tags: solidity, transactions, web3js, ether, contract-invocation

How do I fund Solidity contracts with Ether? The example in the Solidity FAQ, http://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/develop/frequently-asked-questions.html#store-ether-in-a-contract, funds a contract via the contract's constructor. Can you do the same outside of the constructor?

Some background; I want a contract to be able to send Ether to someone's address via something like `recipient.send(169000000000000000000);`

Anyway, here's the output from my `geth` console:

```
>eth.getBalance(eth.coinbase)
169531250000000000000
```

So I have ~169 Ether to play with. Great! So I tried this:

```
contract A {
    function fund() public {
        Funded(msg.sender,msg.value);
    }    
}
```

Which I then wanted to fund with the following .js call:

```
const exchangerContract = web3.eth.contract(exchangerAbi)
const contractAddress = '0x0d2bbe5af1fa1eaebc5ad6e27aa27a7328dc58bc'
const contract = exchangerContract.at(contractAddress)
contract.fund({from: web3.eth.accounts[0], value: web3.toWei(100,"ether")})
```

Unfortunately, that doesn't seem to work; I get the following when I load up the console:

```
>eth.getBalance('0x0d2bbe5af1fa1eaebc5ad6e27aa27a7328dc58bc')
0
```

So, wondering if my .js was faulty, I tried the same in the console:

```
>eth.sendTransaction({from: eth.coinbase, to: '0x0d2bbe5af1fa1eaebc5ad6e27aa27a7328dc58bc', value: web3.toWei(100, "ether")})
"0x136ae6919bd2640425b03633b6709c3863d96600da6ca0c61956f694bbe62384"
>eth.getBalance('0x0d2bbe5af1fa1eaebc5ad6e27aa27a7328dc58bc')
0
```

Boo :( So then I wondered if it was possible to send Ether at all! But:

```
>personal.newAccount()
Passphrase: 
Repeat passphrase: 
"0x5e610b6696683e1c4173bd949279fd6127d8b808"
> eth.getBalance(eth.coinbase)
169531250000000000000
> eth.getBalance(eth.accounts[1])
0
> eth.sendTransaction({from: eth.coinbase, to: eth.accounts[1], value: web3.toWei(169, "ether")})
"0x136ae6919bd2640425b03633b6709c3863d96600da6ca0c61956f694bbe62384"
> eth.getBalance(eth.accounts[1])
169000000000000000000
```

So it seems I can send Ether to a non-contract address, after all. Phew!

How do I do the same to contract addresses?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Yes**, ether can be sent to a contract outside of its constructor.

The recommended way is to invoke a function in the contract [(Receiving Ether / the fallback function)](https://blog.ethereum.org/2016/06/10/smart-contract-security), and the function can [do more instead of just log an event](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/5992/how-much-computation-can-be-done-in-a-fallback-function).

Since [Solidity 0.4](https://github.com/ethereum/solidity/blob/develop/Changelog.md#040-2016-09-08), the `payable` modifier needs to be attached to the function or fallback function.

The fallback function could be made `payable`, but that means other people can accidentally send ether to the contract.  This kind of removes the benefit of `payable`, which Solidity added so that contracts didn't have to implement their own modifier to reject ether and attach it to most of their functions.

> Functions that want to receive Ether have to specify the new payable
>   modifier (otherwise they throw).
>
> Contracts that want to receive Ether
>   with a plain "send" have to implement a fallback function with the
>   payable modifier. Contracts now throw if no payable fallback function
>   is defined and no function matches the signature.

Comment: Yay! nice one! So this works:

function() payable {
    Funded(msg.sender, msg.value);
  }

And then calling it this way:

web3.eth.sendTransaction({from: adminAccount, to: contractAddress, value: web3.toWei(100,"ether")})

...funds the contract with 100 Ether :) 

Thanks!

Comment: Regarding: "The fallback function could be made payable, but that means other people can accidentally send ether to the contract." Could that be prevented by adding the `onlyOwner` modifier to the fallback function (as described here: http://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/develop/contracts.html)?

Comment: Yes, adding another modifier like `onlyOwner` can prevent other addresses sending ether.