# How can you call a payable function in another contract with arguments and send funds?

Tags: solidity, contract-development, contract-design, contract-invocation

I have a contract named `Call`:

```
contract Call {
  ...
  function () payable {
    // TODO: Call the call function in the main contract
    // and forward all funds (msg.value) sent to this contract
    // and passing in the following data: msg.sender
  }
}
```

Here is the `Main` contract:

```
contract Main {
  ...
  function call(address senderAddress) public {
    // Make the code in here run when someone sends ethers to the Call contract
  }
}
```

So, I want to have it so that whenever someone sends ethers the `Call` contract, it forwards all the ethers to the `Main` contract while running the `call` function in the `Main` contract with the necessary arguments.

Can this be done?

Answer (score 59, accepted):

**Update** per @Girish comment, in Solidity 0.6+ the syntax has changed to:
`address.function{value:msg.value}(arg1, arg2, arg3)`

---

### Original

The general syntax for calling a function in another contract with arguments and sending funds is: `address.func.value(amount)(arg1, arg2, arg3)`

`func` needs to have the `payable` modifier (for Solidity 0.4+).

Completing @Edmund's answer with these important details, here's an example that compiles:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.0;

contract PayMain {
  Main main;
  function PayMain(address _m) {
     main = Main(_m);
  }
  function () payable {
    // Call the handlePayment function in the main contract
    // and forward all funds (msg.value) sent to this contract
    // and passing in the following data: msg.sender
    main.handlePayment.value(msg.value)(msg.sender);
  }
}

contract Main {
  function handlePayment(address senderAddress) payable public {
      // senderAddress in this example could be removed since msg.sender can be used directly
  }
}
```

Also emphasizing what he wrote:

> Be aware that this will only work if the people sending the funds send
>   enough gas to cover the call to Main and whatever you do in it.

Comment: about your comment about `msg.sender`, the value of `msg.sender` will be the address of `PayMin`

Comment: As of Solidity 0.6.0, address.function.value(amount)(arg1, arg2, arg3) is deprecated. 
Use address.function{value:msg.value}(arg1, arg2, arg3) instead.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, this can be done. Don't call `call` "call" though - it's asking for trouble.

You'll need the contract that receives the payment to know the address of your Main contract. Imagining it's stored in a variable called main_addr, and Main has a method called handlePayment(), you can call it with something like:

```
Main m = Main(main_addr);
m.handlePayment();
```

This can also take parameters, eg you may want to tell it what you got in `msg.sender` and `msg.value`.

Be aware that this will only work if the people sending the funds send enough gas to cover the call to Main and whatever you do in it. In some situations it may be better to just log an event in the payable contract and handle it later.

Comment: Could you please be more specific on how can this way of calling take further parameters?

Comment: See @eth's answer.

Comment: doesn't answer the question