# How can a contract send a fee to another contract?

Tags: contract-invocation, contract-debugging

Here is the code confusing me:

```
function createRelay () returns (bool success) {
    relay = new Relay()
    bool success = Relay(relay).setRelay(someInt, someAddress);

    if (success) {
        msg.sender.send(fee);
    }
}
```

I'm trying to send a predetermined fee to the new instance of a Relay contract.

Who is `msg.sender`? How do I point to the Relay I want to send the fee to?

Comment: Related: http://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/9705/how-can-you-call-a-payable-function-in-another-contract-with-arguments-and-send

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`msg.sender` is the account (external or another contract) that called `createRelay()`.

If you want to send to your Relay, you write: `relay.send(fee)` or if you want it to be part of the `setRelay` call you do:

```
bool success = relay.setRelay.value(fee)(someInt, someAddress);
```

Comment: Thank you! And the value of fee coming from msg.sender in that case? Or is it coming from "self"?

Comment: It is coming from the contract's balance. If the contract does not have enough to cover the fee, the call fails.

Comment: "...the call fails" and will cause an exception.  This is good, whereas `send` needs to propagate the exception manually: `if (!relay.send(fee)) { throw; }`

Answer (score 2):

There are a few things that are a good reminder and can help minimize debugging.  Here's an example and answer to the question.

```
contract Relay {
    function bal() constant returns (uint) {
        return this.balance;
    }

    function setRelay() payable {
        //...
    }

    function() payable {
    }
}

contract Bar {
    uint public x = 0;
    function foo(Relay contractRelay)  {
        x = 2;
        contractRelay.setRelay.value(100)();  // this is how to send a fee along with setRelay
    }
}
```

1. Reminder to add `payable` modifier to `setRelay` if you want it to get a fee.
2. `contractRelay.setRelay.value(100)()` is the syntax for sending a fee as part of `setRelay`.  I changed the example so that `setRelay` doesn't have arguments, to highlight that the last `()` is important to avoid debugging headaches.
3. If `Bar` has less than 100 wei, than `setRelay` will cause an exception and the transaction will be reverted (`x` will remain 0).

Here are reminders **if instead `foo` just uses `contractRelay.send(100)`**:

- The fallback function should have the `payable` modifier.
- If `Bar` has less than 100 wei, then `contractRelay.send(100)` will **not** cause an exception: `x` will be set to 2.  A general recommendation is to always check the return value of `send`, and in this case

the following is probably desired:

```
if (!contractRelay.send(100)) {
    throw;
}
```

Comment: This was incredibly helpful. Thank you for expanding on my question.

Comment: Glad it's helpful: don't want others to spend much time with unnecessary debugging or writing less secure contracts.