# send ethers from one contract to another

Tags: solidity, transactions, contract-design, ether, ethereum-classic

I am wondering how can I have ethers in my contract. I have 2 contracts associated with different accounts.

I want to send ethers from one contract to another but how do I have ethers in my contract first to be able to send it ?

Here is the example:

```
contract ethertransfer {    
  function fundtransfer(address etherreceiver, uint256 amount) {
    if(!etherreceiver.send(amount)) {
       throw;
    }
  }
}

contract etherreceiver {

  function etherreceiver() {      
  }
}
```

Answer (score 14):

1. Send Ether to your contract (`ethertransfer`) from the **external account** (a term for user controlled accounts). To be able to make it, you need to have a `payable` function in your contract (which might be **the fallback function**
   https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/latest/contracts.html#fallback-function). Payable function is the function with the `payable` modifier (e.g. `function receivePayment() payable {}`). 
   Then you need to send transaction (if fallback function is defined) to the contract or call the function on your contract (if you decided to have one to receive payments). You may use *web3* client to interact with your contact.
2. It's almost the same when sending Ether from one contract to the other. The *target* contract need to have `payable` function as well (it might be again: the fallback function or any other).

   - If the fallback function is defined:
     use `etherreceiver.transfer(100)` or `etherreceiver.send(100)`
   - If there is custom function defined use
     `etherreciver.myPayableFunction.value(100)(myArgument1, myArgument2)`

Further reading: I recommend to read the section regarding `modifiers` it will help you understand what `payable` is:
https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/latest/contracts.html#function-modifiers

Comment: UPDATE: in Solidity 0.6+ the syntax has changed to: `address.function{value:msg.value}(arg1, arg2, arg3)` for custom payable function call https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/9705/how-can-you-call-a-payable-function-in-another-contract-with-arguments-and-send

Answer (score 9):

Simplest approach is a `payable` function, then send it funds from a regular account.

```
contract ethertransfer{

    function payMe() payable returns(bool success) {
        return true;
    }

    function fundtransfer(address etherreceiver, uint256 amount){
        if(!etherreceiver.send(amount)){
           throw;
        }    
    }
}


contract etherreceiver{       
    function etherreceiver(){          
    }    
}
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 3):

As mentioned before, define a payable function to receive the funds, e.g.:

```
function fund() payable returns(bool success) {
}
```

Then call this function and provide the ethers in the value field.

After the tx succeeds define a function in which you use `send()`, e.g.:

```
contract_destination_address.send(amount);
```

Answer (score 2):

1) **Send Ether to your contract**

```
 Step-1: Create a payable method in your contract just to receive some ether. 
         Better use empty payable fallback method(Can just use the contract address to send ether)
```

**Ex:**

[image]

```
 Step-2: Send the transaction to your contract using web3js.
```

2) **Send Ether from one contract to another contract**

This can be best illustrated using an example

```
**Ex:**
```

//Contract to receive Ether from another Contract

contract TransferEtherTo{

```
function getBalance() returns(uint){
    return address(this).balance;
}

//Empty payable fallback method just to receive some
 function() payable{
}
```

}

//************************************************************///

//Contract to send Ether to another Contract

contract TransferEtherFrom{

```
//Declaring an instance of TransferEtherTo contract
TransferEtherTo instance;

constructor(){
    //Initializing TransferEtherTo contract
    instance = new TransferEtherTo();
}

//Returns balance of TransferEtherFrom contract
function getBalance() returns(uint){
    return address(this).balance;
}

//Returns balance of TransferEtherTo contract
function getBalanceInstance() returns(uint){
    return instance.getBalance();
}
//Transfers ether to other contract
function transfer() payable{
    address(instance).send(msg.value);
}

//Fallback function to receive and transfer Ether
function() payable{
    address(instance).send(msg.value);
}
```

}

All the ethers sent to **TransferEtherFrom** contract(through fallback or transfer() methods) will be sent to **TransferEtherTo** contract.

Answer (score 1):

> the sender contract

```
     contract theSender {

     /*Harcoding receiver contract address, one can also use contructor to assign 
      address */
     address payable theReceiverContractAddress;
     theReceiverContractAddress = '0x01...'

     //this is an empty function to receive ether from wallet accounts using web3
     function receiverether() external payable {}

     function balanceof() { 
      return address(this).balance;
      }

     /*this will tranfer the ether stored at this contract's address to the below 
     address */
     function debit() external{ theReceiverContractAddress.transfer(value);}

}
```

> Now the receiving contract

```
contract theReceiver{

/*this is required to receive ether from any source, this will store received ether in 
this contract's address */ 

receive() external payable{}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

For this, you have to make the function that is calling the `address.transfer` as `payable`. Plus there should be a payable function in the receiving contract too.

```
contract ethertransfer {    
  function fundtransfer(address etherreceiver, uint256 amount) public payable {
    if(!etherreceiver.transfer(amount)) {
       throw;
    }
  }
}

contract etherreceiver {

  function etherreceiver() external payable{      
  }
}
```

Now, when you call the *fundtransfer()* function, just put in the address of the contract *etherreceiver*, and the number of ethers you want to transfer.

After that, while calling the function from desired place(remix/web3js), just put in the value = *no. of ethers*, this will deduct the no. of ethers from the account calling the `fundtransfer()` and transfer the `value-amount` no of ethers to the etherreceiver contract.