# How to send ether to a contract in truffle test?

Tags: truffle

For some reason I cant figure out how to send ether to a contract when testing in truffle. This is my attempt:

```
 await myContract.send(10, {from: accounts[0]});
```

the error message is:

```
 Error: VM Exception while processing transaction: revert
```

I get the same error message if I try:

```
 let txHash = await web3.eth.sendTransaction({from: accounts[0], to: myContract.address, value: 10 });
```

Any idea how to get this to work?

Thanks!

Comment: To send ether to a contract you need to declare a function as `payable`. See this for example https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/9705/how-can-you-call-a-payable-function-in-another-contract-with-arguments-and-send

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### Fallback functions

To create a contract which can receive eth via the `.send()` method, you need to declare a fallback function in your contract.

It's pretty easy to do this by simply creating a payable function with no name in your contract like this:

```
// @notice Will receive any eth sent to the contract
function () external payable {
}
```

If you want to do anything with the funds inside a **payable** function you can use the `msg.sender` and `msg.value` variables to work out who and how much was sent.

#### Full example:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.19;

/// @title An example contract that demonstrates making a payment via the send function
contract Test {
  /// @notice Logs the address of the sender and amounts paid to the contract
  event Paid(address indexed _from, uint _value);

  /// @notice Any funds sent to this function will be unrecoverable
  /// @dev This function receives funds, there is currently no way to send funds back
  function () external payable {
    Paid(msg.sender, msg.value);
  }
}
```

#### Output:

When the above contract is compiled, created and send funds, you get the following output:

```
truffle(develop)> Test.new().then(c => c.send(10, {from: '0x627306090abab3a6e1400e9345bc60c78a8bef57'}).then(tx => {console.log(tx.tx); tx.logs.length && console.log(tx.logs[0].event, tx.logs[0].args)}))
0x911ceb59724001b3cb99a035281745b4af5b02a10a1c79906b4c527f8c462db8
Paid { _from: '0x627306090abab3a6e1400e9345bc60c78a8bef57',
  _value: BigNumber { s: 1, e: 1, c: [ 10 ] } }
```

Comment: How we can add test eth in an account without sending it from another account using web3?

Comment: Event invocations have to be prefixed by `emit` and use `fallback` instead of `function` in newer Solidity versions. See https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/89833/compiler-solc-expected-a-state-variable-declaration.

Answer (score 11):

You can use web3 method 'sendTransaction'. things to be note that web3 methods always handle ethereum in wei format, so when you transfer ether you should use wei format

first Deploy your contract as follows (assume your contract name is 'myContract')

```
myContract.deployed().then(function(instance){myContract=instance})
```

now use sendTransaction to transfer ether to this contract as follows

```
myContract.sendTransaction({from:web3.eth.coinbase,value:10000000000000000000})
```

youcan use 'toWei' method to find out ether in wei as follows

```
 web3.toWei(10,"ether")
```

Answer (score 2):

For those searching for this Q and just want an answer that matches the Title question:

> Option 2: There's also shorthand for just sending Ether directly:

```
instance.send(web3.utils.toWei(1, "ether")).then(function(result) {
  // (see docs)
});
```

-- https://trufflesuite.com/docs/truffle/getting-started/interacting-with-your-contracts.html

---

For those with a similar situation to OP; your transaction is reverting, which is why it fails. You need to figure out why it is reverting. This can be not having a `fallback` or `receive` function, or code within those functions (or corresponding modifiers, if any).

You may try using Tenderly or Remix to simulate the transaction with more detail.