# how can I send ether and call function in truffle test?

Tags: truffle

From [this](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/42995/how-to-send-ether-to-a-contract-in-truffle-test?noredirect=1&lq=1), I know how to send ether to contract address itself. But I have a function defined as payable, then how can I call and send ether at the same time?

for example, my contract is like this,

```
contract MyTest {
  function DepositEther(address _to, string _title) payable external {
     //do something inside..
  }
}
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Is similar to the syntax proposed in the linked post, you just need to specify the method name also.

```
contractInstance.method.sendTransaction(to, title, { from: accounts[0], value: ..., gas: ... });
```

where `method` is your method name (`DepositEther`) and `contractInstance` is the instance of your contract

Answer (score 3):

Regular functions look like this in truffle:

```
var account = accounts[0];
[...]
myTestInstance.regularFunction(_arg1, _arg2, {from: account});
```

To make it payable, all you have to do is this:

```
var account = accounts[0];
var price = 1000000000000000000; //whatever your price is
[...]
myTestInstance.payableFunction(_arg1, _arg2, {value: price, from: account});
```