# Compiler solc expected a state variable declaration

Tags: solc, payable

I try example from book Mastering Ethereum:

```
contract Faucet {
    function withdraw(uint withdraw_amount) public {
        require(withdraw_amount<=10000000000000000);
        msg.sender.transfer(withdraw_amount);
    }
    function () public payable {}
}
```

Is error:

```
Error: Expected a state variable declaration. If you intended this as a fallback function or a function to handle plain ether transactions, use the "fallback" keyword or the "receive" keyword instead.
--> Faucet.sol:6:32:
|
6 |     function () public payable {}
|                                ^
```

Compiler solc is in version 0.7.4.
How correct it?

Answer (score 24):

instead of using

```
function() public payable {}
```

Use

```
fallback() external payable {}
```

with latest solidity we dont use function keyword.
https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/v0.7.4/contracts.html#fallback-function

See release of 0.6.0
https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/v0.7.4/060-breaking-changes.html#semantic-and-syntactic-changes