# Call a payable function from a smart contract

Tags: solidity

Lets say we have contract A

`contract A{
      function foo(uint8 value) payable{
       require(msg.value !=0)
       do something ...
      }
   }`

and contract B

`contract B{
      function bar(uint8 value) payable{
       calls the function foo of the contract A
      }
   }`

Assume that I have correctly set the addresses and contract B knows the address of contract A. What would be the syntax for calling the function foo?

Doing something like `A.foo(value)` reverts due to the requirement of A.foo().

Answer (score 2):

Duplicate of [Question 9705](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/9705/how-can-you-call-a-payable-function-in-another-contract-with-arguments-and-send). The answer there seems to work perfectly. The syntax is `address.func.value(amount)(arg1, arg2, arg3)`