# Calling and funding a payable function from existing contract balance

Tags: solidity, balances, payable

If smart contract A has a balance of 1 ETH, can I call a payable function on Contract B, from a function in Contract A, with a msg.value that would be effectively withdrawn from the balance of smart contract A? As opposed to calling from EOA.

Answer (score 1):

> The general syntax for calling a function in another contract with arguments and sending funds is: address.func.value(amount)(arg1, arg2, arg3)

From [How can you call a payable function in another contract with arguments and send funds?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/9705/how-can-you-call-a-payable-function-in-another-contract-with-arguments-and-send/9722), which is a duplicate of this question.

Please research your topic a bit more (for example I searched up 'solidity call function payable') before posting; many times you can find your question already on stack overflow.

Welcome to Ethereum Stack Overflow!

Comment: thank you for your response and maybe I should have phrased better/more specifically. I was asking if you could simply "fund" contract B with some sufficient balance of ether that would satisfy the needs of the payable function in Contract B. In this case, the payable function in B needs a value to satisfy oraclize query fee. So maybe the better questions is, will the oraclize auto-deduct its fee from the calling contract balance (contract B)?