# Direct and separate funds into two different payable functions

Tags: solidity, solidity-0.5.x

Basically I have this code where I'm trying to divide a specific amount of ether into two different function calls within the contract.

`function singleTransaction(arg1) payable {
   require(msg.value == 1 ether);
   buy.value(msg.value / 2)(buy_arg); // diff function in contract
   subscribe.value(msg.value / 2)(subscribe_arg); // diff function in contract
}`

But I'm getting this error on migration:
`TypeError: Member "value" not found or not visible after argument-dependent lookup in function (uint256) - did you forget the "payable" modifier?`

I found a different stack exchange article suggesting the format I've posted, so not sure where to go from here.

- Truffle v5
- Solidity 5.0

Comment: This syntax doesn't seem to make much sense. What are `buy` and `subscribe`? It looks from the error like maybe those are functions in the same contract. Internal functions can't be payable, so you can't use that syntax with them. Why not just pass the amount as a parameter? (`foo(msg.value / 2, ...)`)

Answer (score 0):

## TL;DR call payable methods on a different contract

As Michael C says in the previous comment (probably meant to be an answer):

`buy` and `subscribe` look like you mean them to be different methods in the *same* contract. However, the value has already arrived to your contract through the payable `singleTransaction` method, so there's no way to split up the value now: all of the value will go into the current contract's balance if the tx succeeds.

You can call payable methods on a *different* contract, and then send half the value to each one, using the syntax that you used above, and following the advice [in this other answer](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/9722/4670)

The key line below specifies which contract you are expecting to call this payable method on

```
buyContract.buyMethod.value(halfValue)(BUY_ID);
```

The full source file is:

```
import "./SafeMath.sol";

contract Constants {
    uint8 public constant BUY_ID = 1;
    uint8 public constant SUBSCRIBE_ID = 2;
}

contract BuyContract is Constants {

    uint256 public lastAmount;

    function buyMethod(uint8 _buyArg) payable public {
        require(_buyArg == BUY_ID);
        lastAmount = msg.value;
    }

}

contract SubscribeContract is Constants {

    uint256 public lastAmount;

    function subscribeMethod(uint8 _subscribeArg) payable public {
        require(_subscribeArg == SUBSCRIBE_ID);
        lastAmount = msg.value;
    }

}

contract MyContract is Constants {
    using SafeMath for uint256;

  function singleTransaction(
      address _buyAddress,
      address _subscribeAddress
  ) payable public {
      BuyContract buyContract = BuyContract(_buyAddress);
      SubscribeContract subContract = SubscribeContract(_subscribeAddress);
      uint256 halfValue = msg.value.div(2);
      buyContract.buyMethod.value(halfValue)(BUY_ID);
      subContract.subscribeMethod.value(halfValue)(SUBSCRIBE_ID);
  }

}
```

Here's the full example in this gist:
https://gist.github.com/cryptogoth/9bb1caa9193adb73dc640ec8f979963e