# How to deposit to WETH in Solidity 0.6 and above?

Tags: solidity, ether, address.transfer, solidity-0.6.x

Solidity 0.6.0 [introduced](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.7.5/060-breaking-changes.html) a breaking change in how ETH transfers are performed. The following doesn't work anymore:

```
weth.deposit.value(amount)();
```

What is the latest syntax for depositing ETH into the [WETH](https://etherscan.io/token/0xc02aaa39b223fe8d0a0e5c4f27ead9083c756cc2) contract?

Comment: `weth.deposit{value: amount}();` as far as I remember.

Comment: And BTW, WETH is not a fundamental part of the Ethereum standard or infrastructure. It's an ERC20 contract implemented by a "privately held" company. So the question here is generally for any payable function on any contract (I mean, that's how the question should be formulated IMO).

Comment: @goodvibration It depends on your standards, but to me holding 5,411,942 ETH (approximately $316M at the time of writing this) makes WETH a rather important public good in the Ethereum ecosystem.

Comment: I included WETH in the formulation because I wanted this q&a to be very specific. Humans like specific examples. There is already another [thread about payable functions in general](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/9705/how-can-you-call-a-payable-function-in-another-contract-with-arguments-and-send).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Solidity 0.6 and 0.7

Here's a simple implementation that can you try out in [Remix](https://remix.ethereum.org):

```
pragma solidity >=0.6.0;

interface WethLike {
    function deposit() external payable;

    function withdraw(uint256) external;
}

contract MyContract {
  WethLike weth;

  constructor(WethLike weth_) {
    weth = weth_;
  }

  function foo() external payable {
    weth.deposit{ value: msg.value }();
  }
}
```

Comment: Hello. I have followed what you said, but the Weth is not transferred to user's wallet.