# Error : Using ".value(...)" is deprecated. Use "{value: ...}" instead

Tags: solidity, smart-contract-wallets, exceptions

Somebody please help me find the correct pattern to make this solidity error disappear, I'm using specifically solc^0.8.0, here is my code snippet :

```
function fundAirline() 
    isAirlineRegistered(msg.sender) 
    requireIsOperational
    paidEnough(FUNDING_REQUIRED) 
    checkValue(FUNDING_REQUIRED) external payable {
    
    flightSurety.fundAirline.value(msg.value)(msg.sender); // the problem is in this line
    emit AirlineFunded(flightSurety.getAirlineName(msg.sender), msg.sender); 
}
```

The problem is in the line : `flightSurety.fundAirline.value(msg.value)(msg.sender);` it raise the following complaining :

> Using ".value(...)" is deprecated. Use "{value: ...}" instead.

Thank you.

Comment: instead of .value(msg.value), use {value: msg.value}
The line becomes flightSurety.fundAirline{value: msg.value}(msg.sender);

Comment: Yes, I use it, and it fixed my code, thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had faced this on invoking call and had found from Solidity docs that gas and value parameters need to be passed in curly brackets now:

```
address(nameReg).call{gas: 1000000, value: 1 ether}(abi.encodeWithSignature("register(string)", "MyName"));
```

Here's the code snippet reflecting the issue I faced with the fix.

CODE WITH SIMILAR PROBLEM:

```
(bool success, ) = payable(msg.sender).call.value(withdrawalAmt)('');
```

FIX:

```
(bool success, ) = payable(msg.sender).call{ value: withdrawalAmt }('');
```

Though you are NOT using call, the base principle remains the same as you are invoking a contract function and so, applying above fix to your issue:

CODE WITH PROBLEM:

```
flightSurety.fundAirline.value(msg.value)(msg.sender);
```

PROPOSED FIX*****

```
flightSurety.fundAirline{ value: msg.value }(msg.sender);
```

---

Also came across this on ESE, it provides relevant clarity: [Ethereum.StackExchange - Calling a payable function in another contract with value and arguments](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/9705/how-can-you-call-a-payable-function-in-another-contract-with-arguments-and-send)

Hope this helps.

Comment: The error vanished after using the proposed code, thank you so much :)

Comment: @Yaseenix: Thanks for confirming - glad that I could be of help.