# Send a transaction with value to the contract fail

Tags: solidity, transactions, remix

I'm using Ropsten Testnet and Remix.

Is there an obvious error in this code? Why does not he accept eth.

function () payable public {
        buy();
    }

```
function buy () payable public whenNotPaused beforeDeadline afterStartTime saleNotClosed {
    require(msg.value >= minContribution);

    // Update the sender's balance of wei contributed and the amount raised
    uint amount = msg.value;
    uint currentBalance = balanceOf[msg.sender];
    balanceOf[msg.sender] = currentBalance.add(amount);
    amountRaised = amountRaised.add(amount);

    // Compute the number of tokens to be rewarded to the sender
    // Note: it's important for this calculation that both wei
    // and PDT have the same number of decimal places (18)
    uint numTokens = amount.mul(rate);

    // Transfer the tokens from the crowdsale supply to the sender
    if (tokenReward.transferFrom(tokenReward.owner(), msg.sender, numTokens)) {
        FundTransfer(msg.sender, amount, true);
        // Check if the funding goal or cap have been reached
        // TODO check impact on gas cost
        checkFundingGoal();
        checkFundingCap();
    }
    else {
        revert();
    }
}
```

The Crowdsale contract has an allowance. The gas limit has been increased in many ways. My ether wallet warning !
[image]

The full code is here:
https://ropsten.etherscan.io/address/0x500c3ff2c1a561cd0fda1cf0c77fe0d17af5fda5

What I'm missing here?.
Thank you in advance for your answer. The last question was unanswered, so I ask again !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the fallback function can't execute your buy() function as it has only a stipend of 2300 gas.
check [How much computation can be done in a fallback function?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/5992/how-much-computation-can-be-done-in-a-fallback-function)

so remove it from the fallback function and call it directly

```
function () payable public {  }

function buy () payable public whenNotPaused beforeDeadline afterStartTime saleNotClosed {
    require(msg.value >= minContribution);

    // Update the sender's balance of wei contributed and the amount raised
    uint amount = msg.value;
    uint currentBalance = balanceOf[msg.sender];
    balanceOf[msg.sender] = currentBalance.add(amount);
    amountRaised = amountRaised.add(amount);

    // Compute the number of tokens to be rewarded to the sender
    // Note: it's important for this calculation that both wei
    // and PDT have the same number of decimal places (18)
    uint numTokens = amount.mul(rate);

    // Transfer the tokens from the crowdsale supply to the sender
    if (tokenReward.transferFrom(tokenReward.owner(), msg.sender, numTokens)) {
        FundTransfer(msg.sender, amount, true);
        // Check if the funding goal or cap have been reached
        // TODO check impact on gas cost
        checkFundingGoal();
        checkFundingCap();
    }
    else {
        revert();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for answering. Thorkil Værge how to correct this. I'm not programmer. Without  if (tokenReward.transferFrom(tokenReward.owner(), msg.sender, numTokens)) { , works fine. 
I'm just not sure when I will delete this lines I will be able to distribute tokens. Badr Bellaj - How to make this fallback function cheaper. What should I remowe?

Comment: Badr Bellaj , Thank You for the correction but this give me error in Remix

Comment: @Robert now it should be ok. don't forget to accept the answer if you think it's helpful

Comment: Badr Bellaj You was right. Works!

Answer (score 0):

The function call that is failing is a call to this method:

```
function setTokenOffering(address offeringAddr, uint256 amountForSale) external onlyOwner onlyTokenOfferingAddrNotSet {
        require(!transferEnabled);

        uint256 amount = (amountForSale == 0) ? TokenAllowance : amountForSale;
        require(amount <= TokenAllowance);

        approve(offeringAddr, amount);
        tokenAllowanceAddr = offeringAddr;

    }
```

You have already called the `enableTransfer` function which sets `transferEnabled` to true. So the first line in the above method `require(!transferEnabled);` will fail and the execution will stop.