# Calling a smart-contract fallback function from another contract

Tags: solidity, contract-development

```
contract A {
   function one() public {
      //transfer to B to call its fallback function
      B(addressB).transfer(value);
   }

contract B {
   function() external payable {
       someaddress.transfer(msg.value);
   }
```

In reality, is it impossible to do so? 
Otherwise, if I create an empty B's fallback function then it works. Or if I create simple function with `someaddress.transfer(msg.value);` and call this function from `contract A` as `B(address).someFunction.value(value)()` then it also works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The thing is that the transfer method allows for 2300 gas stipend. Because the fallback has a transfer again, 2300 won't be enough. You can use

```
addressB.call.value(msg.value)()
```

which will pass all the available gas or you can do:

```
addressB.call.value(msg.value).gas(maxGas)()
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 2):

You can decide how much gas you give to the transfer.

The basic `transfer` or `send` give a default gas of only *2300* which is not enough for almost anything - you can just emit a log event and that's about it.

But if you use the pattern of `recipient.call.value(1)()` you can specify the amount of gas you pass to the recipient. You can read more for example here: https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/5993/31933