# Receiving and manipulating transaction data in smart contract

Tags: solidity, transactions, fallback-function

The idea is simple: you can send transactions using any ethereum wallet, and every such wallet has an additional data to send called "transaction data". For example, I want users to be able to type in that data field name of the product they are purchasing, a simple string or maybe an integer value (index of a product). Is that possible? I just want users be able to not only interact with my contract using metamask or mist, but also just using their maybe online wallets or etc.

As I read in docs, I have to use a standard fallback payable function, like

```
contract Test {
   function() payable {}
}
```

and somehow read the `msg.data`. How is that possible to read it? 
I searched the questions but none of them had the right answer.
But there is more: fallback function executes only `2300 gas`, so how can I handle it then?

Answer (score 1):

The limit of `2300 gas` was introduced to reduce the risk of malicious behaviour (like `re-entrant attack` used in the famous DAO hack) from contracts which receive ether. The limit is enough to submit an `event` so at worse your application may listen to that event and then process further the purchase.

However, this limit is not connected to the `default fallback` function but to the sending methods: `send()` and `transfer()`. For the latter, you are able to override the limit using `.gas(xxx)` method. And you can obviously use the low level `call()` function that goes without any limitations to gas.

You can add data to any of this function, remember to encode it first using tools such as [this](http://string-functions.com/string-hex.aspx).

Comment: I mean only sending transactions to a contract number using any wallet. That means I can't really choose functions, I can only send ether to a 'fallback' function. How is that possible to decode the data in the contract?

Comment: Yes, all of the parameters (like product name or index) are passed in `msg.data`. Here you can find some detailed instruction on how to parse them https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/5684/accessing-the-last-function-parameter-from-msg-data.

Comment: Am I rigth that in my contract I should work with that msg.data through function() payable {} ?

Comment: Yes, but be aware of the gas limitation. It may be wiser to submit an event containing `msg.data` from payable function and process it further in another place.