# What is msg.data?

Tags: solidity, web3js, calldata

Is `msg.data` equal to `{from: addr1, data:something}`?

How to handle the data 'something'?

when execution this code:

```
web3.eth.sendTransaction({from: ..., to: addressOfE, data: something});
```

how to read the "data: something " ? 
For example: `data: web3.toHex('something')`

thank you!

update 4, 7 2017

demo:
I put a event function in sendCoin function.

```
"event LogMsgData(bytes calldata);" 
when i call this, 
meta.sendCoin(receiver, amount, {from: account, data:web3.toHex('test'), gas:500000});
```

the LogMsgData print this:

```
//"0x90b98a11     -> MethodID
//000000000000000000000000f178589cf1ef5af554863d8cef601c9fc02ca2ed   -> receiver address 
//0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000002"  -> the amount
```

and where is `{from: account,data:web3.toHex('test'),gas:500000}` ?

Comment: Welcome. Feel free to include details about what you're trying to accomplish and the context. It might help people recognize what you want to know. Have a look over here from information that might help: http://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/8076/what-exactly-is-inside-msg-data

Comment: Thanks, all parameters can be accessed from msg.data (EVM term is calldata) .  http://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/5684/accessing-the-last-function-parameter-from-msg-data

Answer (score 31):

I had to dig a little deeper into the contents of msg.data for this [feature](https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-solidity/issues/891).

I thought it would be worth noting that variable length parameters like arrays, bytes and strings produce a more complex structured msg.data.

Given the following method:

```
function getMsgData(
  address _address,
  bytes _bytes,
  uint _int,
  uint[] _array,
  string _string
 )
  external
  returns (bytes)
 {
   return msg.data;
 }
```

If we call this method the following params:

```
contract.getMsgData(
 someAddress,
 web3.toHex('my bytes'),
 12,
 [1, 4, 412],
 'thisislargerthanthirtytwobytesstring'
);
```

The response would be broken down like this:

```
0x
d1621754 // (1) methodId
000000000000000000000000c6e012db5298275a4c11b3e07d2caba88473fce1 // (2) "_address"
00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000a0 // (3) location of start of "_bytes" data (item 7) = 160 bytes
000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000c // (4) "_val" = 12
00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000e0 // (5) location of start of "_array" data (item 9) = 224 bytes
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000160 // (6) location of start of "_string" data (item 13) = 352 bytes
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000008 // (7) size of "_bytes" data in bytes (32 bytes)
6d79206279746573000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000 // (8) "_bytes" data padded to 32 bytes
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000003 // (9) length of "_array" data = 3
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001 // (10) _array[0] value = 1
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000004 // (11) _array[2] value = 4
000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000019c // (12) _array[3] value = 412
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000024 // (13) size of "_string" data in bytes (64 bytes)
7468697369736c61726765727468616e74686972747974776f6279746573737472696e670..0 // (14) "_string" data padded to 64 bytes
```

You can see that strings, bytes and arrays all have their data size and data appended to the end of msg.data. In place of where the parameters data would normally appear you have a 32 byte interger which describes the location of the params data.

Comment: Good first post!

Comment: Haha, thanks! I'll consider 10-year debt of leaching answers of stack overflow repaid.

Answer (score 9):

1. Yes, in `web3.eth.sendTransaction({from: ..., to: addressOfE, data: something});`, then in contract E, `msg.data` will be the something.
2. However, most of the time a contract handles `msg.data` indirectly and easily.

For example, if you have a [contract instance in web3.js](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JavaScript-API#example-51)

```
// creation of contract object
var MyContract = web3.eth.contract(abi);

// initiate contract for an address
var myContractInstance = MyContract.at('0x78e97bcc5b5dd9ed228fed7a4887c0d7287344a9');

myContractInstance.myStateChangingMethod('someParam1', 23, {value: 200, gas: 2000}, function(err, result){ ... });
```

then in Solidity, the contract at 0x78e9... would have something like

`function myStateChangingMethod(string someStr, uint someNumber)` and the contract doesn't have to parse `msg.data` -- because `someStr` will have the value `someParam1` and `someNumber` will have the value `23`.

Note: Do not mix up #1 and #2.  For example, there is no `data` object when invoking `myStateChangingMethod` in #2: use a third parameter instead.

---

3. Another example is using [Solidity's `call`](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/8270/what-does-soliditys-call-function-mean).  For example, a contract C sends a message to D using `D.call(something)`, then `msg.data` will be the something.

Here is a "proof" to try in Remix:

```
contract C {
    // in Remix, pass bytes as an array like: // ["0x00","0xaa", "0xff"]
    function test(address addressOfD, bytes bb) {
        addressOfD.call(bb);
    }
}

contract D {
    event LogMsgData(bytes calldata);

    function() {
        LogMsgData(msg.data);
    }
}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: thanks for your answer,  but when execution  web3.eth.sendTransaction({from: ..., to: addressOfE, data: something});  how to read the "data: something " ?  example. data: web3.toHex('something')

Comment: Get the [transaction](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JavaScript-API#web3ethgettransaction) and look at the `input` property? Or do you mean [`getData`](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JavaScript-API#contract-methods)?

Comment: yeah , i want to  access the data:web3.toHex('something') in contract internal , can it be ?

Comment: Are you asking for clarity about point1 of answer above?  If so, in your contract's fallback function have you tried logging `msg.data` like it's done in point3?  (I can edit the answer's point1 to mention the fallback function.)

Comment: Yes, the LogMsgData function only print the parameter "bb",  it didn't print the parameter in {} ,  ex. look upside demo, thank you

Comment: You need to do `myContractInstance.myStateChangingMethod('someParam1', 23, web3.toHex('test'), {value: 200, gas: 2000}, function(err, result){ ... });` instead of `myContractInstance.myStateChangingMethod('someParam1', 23, {value: 200, gas: 2000, data:web3.toHex('test') }, function(err, result){ ... });`  I will add a note to the answer, and these comments should probably be cleaned up and another question should be asked if needed.

Comment: Hi, @eth, After writing the contract C and D code, I'm getting error in Remix that says invalid arrayify value. How can I get your example to work?  transact to C.test errored: Error encoding arguments: Error: invalid arrayify value (argument="value" value=["0x00""0xaa""0xff"] code=INVALID_ARGUMENT version=bytes/5.5.0)

Comment: @IlanAizelmanWS Remix has changed a lot. I think posting a question like this but using 2022 in the title, will help you? https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/13483/how-to-pass-arbitrary-bytes-to-a-function-in-remix

Answer (score 1):

**CONTENT**

`msg.data` = function selector (the function which is called) + function arguments

**SIZE**

It is a dynamic byte array which means, it does not have fixed bytes size.
Selector is **always** 4 bytes, and each argument of the function can be **maxium** 32 bytes. So, bytes size/length of `msg.data` for a simple function with two uint256 parameters is:

4 bytes selector + 32 bytes first argument + 32 second argument = 68 bytes

However, as Solidity uses a 32-byte word size for data storage and memory access, we need to round up 68 to the nearest multiple of 32 bytes. For this reason, the final length of the `msg.data` is:

68 + 28 = 96 bytes