# Transfer files using smart contracts

Tags: contract-development, mist, ethereum-wallet-dapp

I want to be able to transfer files from one Ethereum wallet to another using Mist. Is it possible to this?

The files I am planning to transfer are small files. They would be less than 5mb.

If yes, how is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

By files, do you mean large files. If so, that is not ideal use case for using the chain. The cost wouldn't make sense. You could store the data off chain and keep the hash or url with the contract. Then communicate with that. It is like normally sharing the link of a video instead of the entire video file. Could you decentralised storages for the purpose it that makes sense

Comment: Wanted to comment but can't comment. Please add more details if the answer doesn't suffice.

Comment: I have updated the question details. The files in question are files which would be less than 5mb.

Comment: 5 MB is too large in terms of gas. Please consider your use case and if it is justifiable, have a contract hold the meta data to access the file, if that makes sense

Answer (score 0):

1. read Solidity documantation `msg.data`: [msg.data](http://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/develop/units-and-global-variables.html)
2. have a look at this thread: [what-is-msg-data](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/14037/what-is-msg-data)