# Can confirmed Ethereum transactions be reversible?

Tags: transactions

I need a way to ensure that transactions coming to my non-smartcontract Ethereum wallet can't be reversed. Is it enough to check that each incoming transaction has as least N confirmations just like in Bitcoin world, or I should also ensure that the "data" field ("input" in Parity API) is empty because otherwise it can be exploited in some way?

Answer (score 2):

It's enough to check that each incoming transaction has at least n confirmations.

Answer (score 1):

Wait for X confirmations to ensure that the transactions are part of the cannonical chain.

For more on msg.data check out [What is msg.data?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/14037/what-is-msg-data)