# Deploy contract hangs in Mist

Tags: mist, contract-deployment, abi

I'm not able to deploy any contract (the greeter contract does not work either) using Mist 0.8.6 in Windows. The deployment just hangs there and nothing really happens. Is there a way to figure out what is going on? I've tried restarting Mist but that had no effect.

Thanks.

Edit:

This is the information from one of the contracts: https://testnet.etherscan.io/tx/0x3abd39f86738318ad93d9f183903dc678a77b0b2259a5d7dd3a7079e984e52bc

I'm no expert but it does seem the contract was successfully created. However, it does not show in the Mist browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your contract was sucessfully mined 20 hours ago at [0xf99cb2f121635788ea26177fcb7b8bf878c7756a](https://testnet.etherscan.io/address/0xf99cb2f121635788ea26177fcb7b8bf878c7756a) on testnet.

To add it to mist, go to contracts and click on "watch contract":

[image: mist screenshot of adding a contract]

Enter the name, the contract address and the [ABI](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/q/234/87). This should further allow you to interact with the contract.

Comment: Thanks for the help. But, why isn't Mist doing this automatically? It used to do it just a couple of days ago ...