# How to interact with Smart Contract in private network with 3 nodes using Mist?

Tags: go-ethereum, synchronization, contract-invocation, ethereum-wallet-dapp

I'm looking for a method to interact with a smart contract deployed from the official Ethereum wallet.

My client is Geth,and I've synchronized 3 nodes. How is possible to recall a simple method of smart contract from any node?

Comment: You need the [ABI](http://ethereum.stackexchange.com/q/234/87) and then [call or transact](http://ethereum.stackexchange.com/q/765/87) with it.

Comment: Thank you so much! But can i find a guide about it ?

Answer (score 1):

Easy first-steps tutorial here: https://www.ethereum.org/greeter

You need the ABI and the ADDRESS of the smart contract.

Comment: Thanks  it work ! Can i do the same, to interact with contract, with Ethereum Wallet (Mist) from the section "Watch Contract"?

Comment: i guess, haven't tried Mist yet.

Comment: URL doesn't work any more