# How to know the hex code to use in data to call a specific contract function?

Tags: solidity, transactions, contract-invocation, abi

For instance, on the [BAT ico site](https://basicattentiontoken.org/), you can see [the crowdsale contract](https://etherscan.io/address/0x0D8775F648430679A709E98d2b0Cb6250d2887EF#code) address, the ABI and also a string to use in the data part of your transaction if you don't want to call the contract function using the ABI.

The data to put in the transaction is 0xb4427263 that corresponds to the createTokens() function.

How did they manage to get this 0xb4427263 hex value ?
Did they have to make a transaction using the ABI first then get the data from the transaction or is there a direct way to get the value without sending a transaction ?

Comment: That information is in this question https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/234/what-is-an-abi-and-why-is-it-needed-to-interact-with-contracts

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is an ABI and why is it needed to interact with contracts?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/234/what-is-an-abi-and-why-is-it-needed-to-interact-with-contracts)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For this specific example you take the method signature `createToken()` and compute its SHA3 hash `0xb4427263722d66ea37c3d76cba9c56b0f1a7d6e049effc1f9f75567547fd47eb`, then take the first 4 bytes (8 hex characters) of it and you have `0xb4427263`. Since there are no arguments to pass, that's all of the data.

`web3.sha3("createTokens()").substr(0,10)`

The full specifications for this encoding can be found at https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/Ethereum-Contract-ABI