# How can I get the hexadecimal equivalent for a method name in an Ethereum contract using Python?

Tags: solidity, transactions, contract-invocation, python, abi

The function to call is called `xyz()`.

My code:

```
web3.sha3("xyz()").substr(0,10)
```

Error:

> AttributeError: module 'web3' has no attribute 'sha3'

In newer versions of web3, the above error occurs. What else can be used to get the hexadecimal equivalent of the function name?

**Source of code:** *[How to know the hex code to use in data to call a specific contract function?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/16959/how-to-know-the-hex-code-to-use-in-data-to-call-a-specific-contract-function)* (the solution doesn't work on newer versions of web3)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The hexadecimal equivalent of the method is called [the function selector](https://solidity-by-example.org/function-selector/).

The function selector is the first 4 bytes of Keccak hash of the function *signature*, arguments packed as string types.

You can get this by:

```
>>> from web3 import Web3
>>> Web3.keccak(text="xyz()")
HexBytes('0x356bc81e51224d094b17ccb8f80b1e659fe334bcf15c6240857cce0568cbb0ba')
>>> hex_bytes = Web3.keccak(text="xyz()")
>>> print(hex_bytes[0:4].hex())
0x356bc81e
```

Comment: it is also called `signature` , within the sources it is called signature, but in solidity it is called selector

Comment: Thank you @Nulik. I believed the selector refers to Solidity 4-byte identifier whereas the function signature is a general programming language concept.

Answer (score 3):

you are looking for this:

**encodeFunctionSignature**

```
web3.eth.abi.encodeFunctionSignature(functionName);
```

Encodes the function name to its ABI signature, which are the first 4 bytes of the sha3 hash of the function name including types.

https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.2.11/web3-eth-abi.html

In pythhon there should exist an equivalent call

Comment: I have been searching the equivalent for ages but still didn't manage to find it, do you by any chance know it?