# Find contract address based on ABI

Tags: solidity, etherscan, addresses, abi

I'm trying to find the deployed address of a contract (on Ethereum mainnet) from its ABI or source code. Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Each ABI item generates [function selectors](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/106408/620) or similar byte equivalents. You can search all deployed contract bytecode payloads ever for matches.

There is likely no tool for it, so you need to write one yourself.