# how to retrieve function call address from deployed contract for usage with MetaMask send + transaction data?

Tags: transactions, contract-invocation, metamask, abi, calldata

I've deployed a contract into my testrpc network.

```
$ truffle deploy
Using network 'development'.

Running migration: 1_initial_migration.js
  Deploying Migrations...
  Migrations: 0x9ec9e7fedb27068a70aedf453012bbced070d1e0
Saving successful migration to network...
Saving artifacts...
Running migration: 2_deploy_contracts.js
  Deploying CrowdFunding...
  CrowdFunding: 0x61a235a21078920353dbb719e7c1e6bd8c8e182b
Saving successful migration to network...
Saving artifacts...
```

How do I get the address for the function `contribute` (from the example code for https://dappsforbeginners.wordpress.com/tutorials/contracts-that-send-transactions/) that looks like this:

```
function contribute(uint campaignID) {
    Campaign c = campaigns[campaignID];
    Funder f = c.funders[c.numFunders++];
    f.addr = msg.sender;
    f.amount = msg.value;
    c.amount += f.amount;
}
```

I assume I need to get the function address, and then provide that as a parameters  inside the MetaMask send dialog under `transaction data`. I can send the eth as the amount, correct? Then, `msg.value` and `msg.sender` are provided as context to the call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I assume I need to get the function address, and then provide that as a parameters inside the MetaMask send dialog under `transaction data`. I can send the eth as the amount, correct?

**Yes.**

To get the Method ID (see [What is an ABI and why is it needed to interact with contracts?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/234/what-is-an-abi-and-why-is-it-needed-to-interact-with-contracts)), you need to use canonical types and then hash it with Keccak-256 and take the first 4 bytes.

#### Example

For `contribute(uint)`, you need to use `contribute(uint256)`.

Enter `contribute(uint256)` into a tool like https://emn178.github.io/online-tools/keccak_256.html

You'll get `c1cbbca71c96db867642d5aeca3697d2e3bd24b386562e2b7004d1b0f4fbaaed`

The first 4 bytes (8 hex characters) are `c1cbbca7`.

You can double-check `0xc1cbbca7` by https://www.4byte.directory

```
ID      text signature      bytes signature
3752    contribute(uint256) 0xc1cbbca7
```

`0xc1cbbca7` is what you put in MetaMask's transaction data **BUT** you still need to encode the uint256 parameter to `contribute`.

See https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/Ethereum-Contract-ABI#examples for examples.

**Manually encoding for the ABI can be tricky and prone to mistakes.  You may end up calling the wrong function on the contract, or send your ETH to a function that will not give you what you are looking for.  Be careful and always double-check if you need to do this.**  In this example, you could make a mistake encoding the campaignID and end up sending (and possibly losing) ETH to the wrong campaign.