# How can I prevent risky DATA fields in an Ethereum transaction?

Tags: transactions

The EVM evaluates smart contracts by reading code in the DATA field of an Ethereum transaction. This is why you shouldn't trust someone who asks you to include an unknown series of characters in a transaction.

However, you can also use that DATA field to send basic text messages.

If I want to send a transaction with a basic text message, how can I ensure that I'm not accidentally sending a potentially risky smart contract?

Comment: As you might be doing things off-chain per https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/29717/is-sending-some-datas-in-the-data-field-safe/29766?noredirect=1#comment120750_29766 some ideas from rollups might help you, for example https://research.paradigm.xyz/optimism  I think you will still get better answers if you explain more because it looks like you are jumping to a solution and could be missing other designs.

Comment: Exactly. Unfortunately it's a technically dense field and it's taking a while to penetrate.

Comment: Take your time. You're right asking good questions takes good effort :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just check the recipient of your transaction is an [EOA](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/5828/what-is-an-eoa-account) (and not a smart contract) : an account controlled by a private key that does not "contain" a code (aka a `wallet`).

To verify an address is an EOA, you can use [Etherscan](https://etherscan.io/) or a high-level library such as web3js for example (see this : [How to detect if an address is a contract?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/28521/how-to-detect-if-an-address-is-a-contract/28527)).

Also note that if you send a transaction to a smart contract with random data attached to it, the likelihood that your data matches a valid payload triggering a contract function is very very unlikely.