# Is there a way to extract ABI from a deployed contract?

Tags: contract-development, contract-deployment, abi

I am building a web UI for testing smart contracts and currently I have to supply the ABI for a contract I test. Is there a way to extract the ABI from a deployed contract (preferably programmatically)?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If the source code has been published to Etherscan, then they have an API to retrieve it. From https://etherscan.io/apis#contracts:

> Get Contract ABI for Verified Contract Source Codes
>
> https://api.etherscan.io/api?module=contract&action=getabi&address=0xBB9bc244D798123fDe783fCc1C72d3Bb8C189413&apikey=YourApiKeyToken

Comment: Unfortunately this wont work as I need it for smart contracts running on a private network (Ganache)

Comment: That's correct. In general, there's no way to get the ABI for a contract unless it's been explicitly stored somewhere.

Answer (score 7):

Go to EtherScan > enter the contract address > click on the Contract in the tab section heading > Scroll down to find the Contract ABI > click on the Copy icon to copy it

Answer (score 5):

Yes, there are tools that **try** to recover ABI from bytecode.

For example [porosity](https://github.com/comaeio/porosity) and [mythril](https://github.com/ConsenSys/mythril).

It is not always possible to recover ABI because bytecode does not contain function signatures but only [last 4 bytes of function signature hash](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/234/what-is-an-abi-and-why-is-it-needed-to-interact-with-contracts/1171#1171).

Comment: If you look at potosity or mythril, you need an ABI to Disassemble or Decompilation. There's no way to get an ABI from a deployed contract.

Answer (score 2):

Deployed contracts are stored in bytecode so out of the box you can't extract the source ABI, however there are open source decompiling [tools](https://github.com/comaeio/porosity) that attempt to recover the ABI.

What you can do is store the ABI JSON in [IPFS](https://github.com/ipfs/ipfs) and reference it by it's content hash.

Answer (score 2):

You can also copy your ABI in [Remix](https://remix.ethereum.org/) by going to Compile-->Details(ABI) section[image: ABI]

Answer (score 1):

https://github.com/shazow/whatsabi

I think this is a good answer if someone is looking to get the function signatures, ABI from bytecode. It also has a way to retrieve the function signature in human readable form from 4 byte hash of the function signature.

If the loaders doesn't work you can always find signatures for most used functions here - https://www.4byte.directory/

Here is a code example that I used

```
const { whatsabi } = require("@shazow/whatsabi");

(async () => {
  // Your contract bytecode (hexadecimal)
  const bytecode = "your byte code here";

  // Get an ABI-like list of interfaces
  const abi = whatsabi.abiFromBytecode(bytecode);
  console.dir(abi);

  // We also have a suite of database loaders for convenience
  const signatureLookup = new whatsabi.loaders.OpenChainSignatureLookup();
  for (const interface of abi) {
    const signature = await signatureLookup.loadFunctions(interface.selector);
    console.log(signature);
  }
})();
```

Comment: cool, thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Since you are developing the UI, I supposed you have developed the contract as well. In that case, if you are using **Truffle**, after deploying the contract **you can find the ABI for each contract you deployed in the autogenerated build/contracts** folder in your project, for example /build/contracts/Migrations.json.

Answer (score 0):

If you are deploying by command line, you can read from the file where is previously builded, in the case of hardhat there is a example:

```js
const fs = require("fs")
const path = require("path")

const getTheAbi = () => {
  try {
    const dir = path.resolve(
      __dirname,
      "./artifacts/contracts/HelloWorld.sol/HelloWorld.json"
    )
    const file = fs.readFileSync(dir, "utf8")
    const json = JSON.parse(file)
    const abi = json.abi
    console.log(`abi`, abi)

    return abi
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(`e`, e)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When using React, you can check the ABI of deployed contracts by accessing the artifacts folder that is created after deployment:

`artifacts -> contracts -> smartcontract.sol -> smartcontract.json`

Comment: If you are using **Brownie** for local python deployment, after you use command `brownie compile`, you can find the JSON ABI of your smart contract in this folder:
`build -> contracts -> ContractABC.json`