# Creating raw transactions for sending ERC721 tokens

Tags: web3js, raw-transaction

I was able to create raw transactions for `eth` following this article https://medium.com/blockchain-musings/how-to-create-raw-transactions-in-ethereum-part-1-1df91abdba7c

However, how can I create raw transactions when send ERC721 tokens? More specifically, where do I add the token id field when creating raw transactions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A token transfer operation is actually a **smart contract method call**, which is a bit different than simple ETH sending:

- you'll have to fill the `data:` portion of the tx with the info related to the smart contract method call (more below)
- the `from:` address is the same as in a normal ETH send operation
- the `to:` address is **the address of the smart contract**, not the address of the recipient
- the `value:` field is 0

How to fill the `data` field. The example is done **using `web3js` v1.0+**. 
You'll need to have:

- your [smart contract's ABI](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/234/what-is-an-abi-and-why-is-it-needed-to-interact-with-contracts). Let's say you store that in variable `ctrABI`
- an instance of Web3. Let's say that's stored in variable `web3`
- the address where your ERC721 smart contract is deployed - `ctrAddress`

  ```
  const ctrInstance = new web3.eth.Contract(JSON.parse(ctrABI), ctrAddress)
  const dataField = await ctrInstance.methods.transfer(addrTo, tokenId ).encodeABI();
  ```

And then proceed to build your transaction:

```
const txParams = {
  nonce: '0x6', // Replace by nonce for your account on geth node
  gasPrice: '0x09184e72a000', 
  gasLimit: '0x30000', //modify accordingly
  to: ctrAddress, 
  data: dataField,
  value: '0x00'
};
```

Comment: I tried contract.transfer(to, tokenId ).encodeABI(), however it gives me this error Error: invalid address. After a little bit of search it seems to be because the default address is not set. However, I want to sign this transaction offline, so I don't want to set any value for `web.eth.defaultaccount`. How can I do it?

Comment: In your original post you said you managed to build the raw transaction according to that tutorial. Did you manage to also **sign and broadcast** that transaction? It should work the same way for this transaction type too

Comment: ok, I got it to work like this `contract.transfer.getData(to,tokenId)`. Thanks.

Comment: can you please add the full example on how that `getData()` works? I couldn't find anything in the `web3js` docs regarding to that method

Comment: Basically, I referred from here https://github.com/ethereum/web3.js/issues/1151#issuecomment-341321119

Comment: oh, you're using `web3` v0.2x.x. My example is for the newer `web3` v1.0+.
If my answer helped you, please upvote & accept it, so others can also recognize it as helpful info.

Comment: Actually, I haven't been able to make a successful transaction yet. I get this error `ERC-20 Token Transfer Error` even though I am trying to send ERC721 tokens. I even created a new question for it https://is.gd/ZbMAUx.

Comment: I got the transaction to work using the steps you described by upgrading web3.js to `1.0.0-beta.36`. If you could just mention the web.js version in your answer, I will accept it.

Comment: yes, that's a good observation. I updated my answer to state that explicitly.