# Why do I need to have exact same code to load contract from address in Remix IDE?

Tags: remix, contract-invocation

I tried to interact with the deployed contract and i don't have its code. so i found out the contract address and tried to load contract from address in Remix IDE! isn't this possible? WHY?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remix IDE is a programmer tool. Its primary purpose is to help you code, test and debug your smart contracts.

> I tried to interact with the deployed contract and i don't have its code.

In this case you are not a developer but a layman user. A non-expert user does not use Remix to transact/interact with the smart contract. You are bound to use the UI or API your dapp developer provided to you. So, since Remix does not the know what functions or api your smart contract has, having its address only will not help you to interact with it. You need to know its ABI as well.

[Application Binary Interface](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/234/what-is-an-abi-and-why-is-it-needed-to-interact-with-contracts) provides you the public function interface. Get the contract ABI. Construct a simple contract interface based on its ABI with the public function declarations only and you will be ready to interact with the contract from Remix.

For example, following is ABI from an unknown contract :

```
[
{
    "constant": true,
    "inputs": [
        {
            "name": "a",
            "type": "string"
        }
    ],
    "name": "check",
    "outputs": [
        {
            "name": "",
            "type": "string"
        }
    ],
    "payable": false,
    "stateMutability": "pure",
    "type": "function"
}
]
```

Contract interface constructed from the abi :

```
contract Test {
  function check(string a) public pure returns(string);
}
```

Now, load the contract `Test` with the actual address and interact with the contract.

Answer (score 1):

You will need the contract ABI (at least) to load it from an address. Remix (or any other client) should know HOW to interact with the contract at that address: function names, parameters format and return values

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, there are 3 options:

1. Have an interface that *declares* the functions you want to access to.
2. Have the exact source code.
3. Have the abi in json format.

All of these options expose the structure of the functions you want to interact with.